# How to develop an Import/Export converter for Compress[]ed data?

Tags: export, import

Mathematica has a cross platform data exchange format, [WDX](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/WDX.html).  Unfortunately importing or exporting large data from/to WDX is very slow.  Using [MX files](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/MX.html) is very fast, but they are not compatible across different computer architectures (32 or 64 bit).

Sometimes it is suggested to [`Compress` the data and write out or read it in manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136266/fast-to-load-cross-platform-alternative-to-mx-files-mathematica).

**Question: How can we extend `Import` and `Export` to allow convenient and fast importing/exporting of arbitrary Mathematica expressions using `Compress`?**

The aim is to define a fast-to-load format, and make importing from it as easy as `Import["data.mmaz"]` or `Import["http://server.com/myfile.mmaz"]`, by integrating it into the `Import`/`Export` framework.  Ideally the format should be recognized based on a file extension.

If there is a better solution than using `Compress`, I'd like to hear it!

Comment: I'm planning to do this today.  I'll probably post an answer in a day or so if I manage.  But I'd like to see some better solutions first :-)

Comment: Not an answer for you but I moved all my data from WDX to a MySQL database a couple of years ago. One of the best things I did.

Comment: @Mike I didn't forget about your suggestion, but this question is mainly about how to develop an Import/Export converter.  I thought it would be good to have a practical tutorial on this here at Mma.SE

Comment: @Szabolcs, further down you mention something about tutorials, have looked at these tutorial/DevelopingAnExportConverter, tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter?

Comment: @ruebenko Yes, I am reading those now.  This was more of an experiment about this: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/194/12  But now I think I asked the wrong question.

Comment: I'm interested in a faster alternative to wdx (ideally as fast as .mx) that is portable. It doesn't have to be Compressed. Any hints?

Comment: @masterxilo Since v10, MX is portable between different OS for as long as the pointer size (64 or 32 bit) is the same. It is also backwards compatible: old MX files can be loaded in newer Mathematica.  Support has confirmed this to me once, and I posted it here, but can't find it now.

Comment: @masterxilo Otherwise the `Compress` trick is good: reading files is very fast, much faster than WDX.  Writing can be a bit slow sometimes.  I don't know of anything else except plain `.m` files.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In this case, developing the converters is dead-easy (which is not a good thing IMO, since it means that we really don't utilize the power of `Import/Export` framework, but rather are adding syntactic sugar):

```
CompressedFormat`CompressedFormatImport[filename_String, options___] :=
    {"Data" -> Uncompress@Import[filename, "String"]};

CompressedFormat`CompressedFormatExport[filename_String, data_, opts___] :=
    Export[filename, Compress@data, "String"];

ImportExport`RegisterImport[
   "CompressedFormat",
   CompressedFormat`CompressedFormatImport
]

ImportExport`RegisterExport[
   "CompressedFormat", 
   CompressedFormat`CompressedFormatExport 
]
```

Example:

```
file = $TemporaryPrefix <> "test";
Export[file, Range[1000000], "CompressedFormat"];
Import[file, {"CompressedFormat", "Data"}] // Length

(* 
  ==>  1000000
*)
```

That said, I think using `Import` - `Export` framework makes much more sense for specific formats where you can specify distinct elements and the framework makes it convenient to create importers for those elements (possibly avoiding full imports when unnecessary). So, for a meaningful exposition of the importer-writing procedure using `Import/Export` framework, some e.g. particular graphics of numerical format would be a better choice IMO, because your stated goal is too general for that.

For that matter, I think that my [large data framework](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36/file-backed-lists-variables-for-handling-large-data/209#209) (perhaps when extended and generalized) will make for a much better case for `Import/Export` framework use, as well as cover your use case and many more, because it:

- Does use `Compress` under the cover
- Uses lazy loading, which opens many possibilities to define certain elements for `Import/Export`, which are loaded individually / efficiently
- Does not have a limitation that the file must fit in memory
- Can be very fast for large files
- In practice, we *use* large files much more frequently than carry them around from platform to platform. My framework can switch from extremely fast .mx files to `Compress`-ed non-.mx files very easily, and the details can be completely hidden from the user, who will just use `Import` in all cases, and have great performance.

In other words, I feel that the direction I outlined there, does contain your suggestion as a special case, and is much more fruitful both for further development of the large-data framework / file format, and for the utilization of the power of the `Import/Export` framework (and, sure enough, this is the direction I will be extending the large-data framework in the future).

Comment: @Szabolcs I did benchmark that before posting - `Import` was 3 times faster. As I said, you are mixing two questions: essential question on loading data fast and cross-platform, with a question of using `Import` - `Export`, which *in this case* is IMO more like syntactic sugar (because your format does not have any complex structure).  I was mostly answering the `Import`/`Export` part, and did not intend to fully answer the loading / saving part (for reasons I outlined). Will look into automatic file extension resolution. Feel free to edit and add benchmarks and whatever else you'd like.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the question was not well formulated.  Now it feels like I should not have asked, epsecially since the tutorials in the documentation are good enough.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think the part regarding the fast cross-platform load/save is a good and valid question - I just think that we'd be better off addressing the more general one by extending the framework I posted. As to the `Import`/`Export`, some simple but composite format like some custom tabular data would probably be better, but then there is an example like that in the docs, as you said.

Comment: @Szabolcs I actually think this was a useful experiment, and now I think that the answer to that question of Mr.Wizard is: ask a question in two cases - either when you *do* know the answer really well, but think that the question and answers would benefit the community, or when you don't, and need it for yourself. Both cases are fine because the asker has put in a lot of thought in either case. Mixing them is not since then this may not be the case. I will post a version of this on meta as another answer, to add to yours.

Comment: I'll clean up the mess later, perhaps European-tonight  ... got to finish some work today

Comment: @Szabolcs I am not sure why you consider this a mess. I have lots of code which uses `Import` with .mx files at the moment, and I would rather not change it to something else in the middle of the project if I wish to transfer the data elsewhere. So I found this useful (and surprisingly easy), and am thankful for the question (and Leonid's answer).

Comment: Regarding file extensions, I found that the mappings are in `SystemFiles/Formats/ExtensionMappings.m`.  They are loaded into the variable ``System`ConvertersDump`ExtensionMappings``, which seems to not be overwritten, only appended to (i.e. manual modifications stay).  If I include an extension in one of these places, `Export` will work correctly without a need to explicitly specify the format.  `Import` will interpret the data as string though.  **Do you think it's okay to ask a new question on this?**

Comment: @Szabolcs I went the other road and hacked a bit the internal code. I was basically appending ``System`ConvertersDump`ExtensionMappings`` directly, but found that this was not enough. Probably your method is preferable. But, for this case, I would simply create a dynamic environment, in which would explicitly overload `Import` and `Export`, perhaps through Gayley - Villegas trick. This has an advantage that whoever uses it, does not have to change anything in the installation, but a possible disadvantage that this code has to be run every time.

Comment: @Szabolcs Well - I'd just repeat what I suggested: ask yourself -  did you put in enough effort :)?  Only you know the answer - if yes, then go ahead and ask. But you don't have to listen to me :)

Answer (score 12):

One simple way to store data in compressed form could use the following:

```
ExportCompressed[filename_,data_]:=
    Export[filename,"Uncompress@"<>"\""<>Compress[data]<>"\"","String"]
```

This simply compresses and prepends the `Uncompress` statement to the resulting string. You can now simply use Get[] to import your data.

I use this to store compressed graphics expressions. Compressing can take a long time (I´d like to see that sped up big time, because several minutes for a few MB of graphics expression is way too long), but mostly you get very good compression.

On the other hand, import of these expressions is really fast. This seems kind of related to the WDX performance.

Comment: Hi Yves, welcome to the party!

Comment: Finally, a question that was not way over my head and/or answered immediately - just what I was looking for to get my foot into the door.

Comment: Hi Yves, welcome to Mathematica.SE!  Could you complement this with some code that integrates this into the `Import` and `Export` functions?

Comment: @Szabolcs: If you Import[] such a file, you get a string. You can then use ToExpression to evaluate this and get back your uncompressed. Using Get[] does the evaluation on the spot. 
I am not sure how to properly splice this transparently into Import and Export.

Comment: @Yves I know that, but directly integrating into the Import/Export framework has many advantages:  I don't need to change my code when I change the file format: just pass it different file names.  Also, web import will work out of the box.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I certainly agree. My version is certainly a quick´n dirty fix that somehow survived the ages in my packages. 
Apart from that, the question is why WDX and Compress are so awfully (sometimes unuseably) slow in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but the extension can be registered using RegisterFormat from the Wolfram Function Repository

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RegisterFormat