# Command to Show Full Output

Tags: output-formatting, display

I have some rather long output from a notebook I run on a remote server.  There is a time limit on processes so I typically do `NotebookSave[]` after any important result.  However, some of these results are truncated.  I would like to force these (and only these) results to be fully expanded before the notebook saves.

I am aware of the `Short` command and the option in preferences to define the maximum byte size of output.  However, I really do not know how large (in bytes or lines) the output is going to be.  (Yes, I could experiment but it seems like there should be an easier way.)  I tried `Short[%,Infinity]` but that didn't work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I think they are just displayed truncated, but the data is there. It's hard to say without more details. Also I think you mean `Short` instead of `Small`.

Comment: Oh, and perhaps it would be better to save the data to a file using Export or DumpSave or similar.

Comment: Indeed, Export [like so](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5457/57) may  work for you.

Comment: Couldn't you just set the preference setting to, say, 75% of your free memory?

Comment: First, once the kernel quits the hidden data is gone.  I too thought it was the FrontEnd just not displaying it all.  However, once you quit the kernel you cannot "Show Full Output".
Yes, I did mean Short (not sure why I was thinking Small).
I could increase the maximum bytes to display but then it's easy to hang the FrontEnd making it try to display something massive.
I considered exporting the data but there are multiple results per notebook and I wanted to keep them bundled.
Looks like Print is probably what I want.

Comment: @EricMock Yes you can. But use `data` (eg a variable) instead of `%` (which is a shortcout for `Out`). It is the Out object that is no longer available. Try it with the example below and you will see, that even after reopening the notebook you can use show more and show less, without re-evaluating the cell.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend that you export your data to a file. But having said that, I think that a normal `Print` will have the same effect as the hypothetical `Short[%,Infinity]`.

For example

```
(*generate some data*)
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10^4];
(*This will display truncated*)
data
(*So will this*)
Short[data, 100]
(*This will display all the data*)
Print[data]
```