# Exporting large expression

Tags: export, import

I generated a huge mathematical expression (~200k terms, impossible to simplify yet) and want to save it for later analysis. Last time I did `Export` to *.nb file and it froze my whole system so I was forced to kill the kernel and generate it again from scratch. How should I do it correctly and then `Import` it back easily?

Comment: Why to do that? By saving the notebook that the said expression is generated you save also the expression. if you want to start from that point you just copy the output expression to an input cell and continue from that point on.

Comment: @Spawn1701D Only true when you actually generated the full output, which generally is not advisable at this size. I'd advise `DumpSave` which is very fast.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Please note that `DumpSave` is not OS and version independent. If you are going to exchange the file with others you might wish to use `Save` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19774/saving-exporting-results-from-findinstance-and-similar-functions) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/how-do-i-save-a-variable-or-function-definition-to-a-file).

Comment: If `DumpSave` does not work for you (eg because it is OS-and version-dependent), perhaps you could try exporting as a string.