# Save a Mathematica notebook evaluated

Tags: evaluation, date-and-time, save, lazy-computations

My notebooks can take some time to evaluate and by quitting Mathematica, I have to reevaluate every definition I've made once I restart Mathematica. Is there a way to tell Mathematica to save the definition one has made so one does not need to reevaluate the notebook at every startup?

Comment: `LocalSymbol` might be what you need.

Comment: Save & Get is what you need.

Comment: `DumpSave` might be your friend. Possible duplicate of: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5450/131

Comment: @M.R. Though LocalSymbol does not always work (like LocalObject also). I somehow have a (probably imperfect, on Windows 10) setup where my `$Username` (rolf) is part of `$UserBaseDirectory` (... Rolf Mertig...) and I have a space in `$UserBaseDirectory` and then I get a privilege violation when using LocalSymbol["x"]=42. So at least on Windows I would not recommend LocalSymbol before these funny windows related problems are fixed.