# Backing up and restoring all Mathematica notebook variables using 'Put' '>>' and 'Get' `<<`

Tags: export, kernel, save

As discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5457/47875) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125/47875), the state of a notebook can be backed up by saving all variables using:

```
DumpSave["backup.mx", "Global`"];
```

These variables can be restored using

```
<< "backup.mx"
```

Is there a way to do the same processes using the shorthand notation of the `Put` function, that is, by using `>>`.

Something like:

```
Names["Globa`*"]>>"backup.mx"`
```

(which doesn't work because `Names` returns a list of strings).

Comment: If you are looking to write to a human-readable text file, like `Put` does, then use `Save` instead of `DumpSave`.  Minor correction: What you show saves the state of the *kernel*. This state is not local to the notebook, so it doesn't really make sense to talk about the "state of the notebook".  If you choose to use a default context local to the notebook (in the Evaluation menu), then symbols won't live in ``Global` `` anymore, so this command won't save them.

Answer (score 4):

You could introduce a wrapper:

```
Dump /: Put[Dump[objects_], file_] := DumpSave[file, objects]
```

Then:

```
Dump["Global`"]>>"foo.mx"
```

will do a [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave) and not a [`Put`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Put).