# Save the data in mathematica

Tags: save

I have been calculated some expansions with NIntegrate and NDSolve in Mathematica and I have a lot of them. Because the calculation of these results takes hours, I want to save it in a file of Mathematica and every time that I need it, just to import it from this file. Do you know in which way that can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save all data in all variables so that loading it is fast?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5450/how-to-save-all-data-in-all-variables-so-that-loading-it-is-fast). Did you try searching the site to see if any of the answers available solves your problem? Did you search Mathematica documentation? With which part of the solutions you found there you need help?

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Please do follow this advice: Start by taking the [tour] and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always show your due diligence, give brief context, include minimal working example of your code in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). Minimum diligence includes searching documentation and site for similar questions and answers. If you don't clarify how your question is different from previous it may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)