# What is the best way to save a large graph object, allowing it to be reloaded quickly in a new kernel?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I generated a very large graph, too large to simply display and manipulate with copy/paste operations.  How can I somehow save the graph to a file to allow it to be rapidly reloaded after I quit out of the kernel and restart Mathematica?

Comment: `Save` or `DumpSave` might be of help. With `DumpSave` you will have the object saved in an mx file so the size will be smaller and will load faster.

Comment: @Spawn1701D So I could simply write Save["SaveFile.mx",G], where G is my graph?

Comment: and `Get["SaveFile.mx"]` or `<<SaveFile.mx` to load it.  Make sure the file is located inside the path of Mathematica and keep in mind that the file can be loaded only to computers with the same kind of OS, so if you make the mx on windows it won't load in Mac OS.

Comment: Instead of `DumpSave`, I recommend `Export`, which can also write MX files, but doesn't store variable *names* inside (only the data).  Or just use `Export["name.mz", Compress[graph], "String"]`.  [See also here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1245/12)

Comment: @Szabolcs Interesting... I did not know that about `Export/Import` and `.mx` files. I typically use `DumpSave` and `Get` with a dedicated internal variable and a wrapper function in my packages i.e. something like `save[file_, var_] := Block[{$var}, DumpSave[file, $var = var];]` and `load[file_] := Block[{$var} = Get@file]`. Oh well... I'll probably keep them the way they are, since it works.

Comment: Why not `Export["graph.txt", Compress[g]]` and then `Import["graph.txt"] // Uncompress` ? I did not see any significant difference in files size and export/import times with .mz .

Comment: @Vitaliy MX is far faster than anything for me, but the Compress approach came in as second.  And Compress is both cross platform and cross version compatible, so that's what I use.  Yves however said that exporting (?) with this Compress method took too much memory for him.  If would really be good if Import/Export had a dedicated format for Mathematica expressions that's fast and small and reasonably compatible between versions.  WDX is small but definitely not fast (takes ages to import for large data).

Answer (score 2):

From the comments of Spawn1710D and Szabolcs:

`Save` or `DumpSave` might be of help. With `DumpSave` you will have the object saved in an mx file so the size will be smaller and will load faster.

You use

```
Save["SaveFile.mx",G]
```

, where G is your graph to save and

```
Get["SaveFile.mx"]
```

or

```
 <<SaveFile.mx
```

to load it. Make sure the file is located inside the path of Mathematica and keep in mind that the file can be loaded only to computers with the same kind of OS, so if you make the mx on windows it won't load in Mac OS.

Instead of `DumpSave`, `Export` can be used. It can also write MX files, but doesn't store variable names inside (only the data). Or just use

```
Export["name.mz", Compress[graph], "String"].
```