# How to implement Raw libraries for importing and analysing raw images as .NEF?

Tags: image-processing

It is the same question that I did in [wolfram community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/440994?p_p_auth=GenVXpe8).

First, I tried import .nef images but math didnt recognize them, so I want to implement the library raw image following the instructions from:

```
[mathematica link][2]
```

How can I do this?

Or is there another way?

I wan to import a .NEF images (NIKON raw format).

a sample of image *.NEF: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2n5y5xjhhqeh7k0/DSC_5133.NEF?dl=0

A related question: [stack question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42153/importing-a-canon-raw-file-cr2)

Comment: It is little different as I ask help for using the library link

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand.  What is your final goal?  If it is to get the data into Mathematica, then the way to go is converting to TIFF, then importing the TIFF file.  You can invoke the converter directly from Mathematica using `Run`.

Comment: If you want to use LibraryLink specifically to create a NEF importer, in the end it won't do anything different than the TIFF-based method.  But doing it is going to take a lot of work. I don't think it's worth it.  For example: first you need to learn how to use LibraryLink, then you could write some C code to use http://www.libraw.org/ to read the data form the NEF and pass it back to Mathematica.   Implementing this involves many small steps, many of which are unrelated to Mathematica.  If for some reason you still decide to do this, I'd recommend to break down the question and ask...

Comment: ...about the individual problems you encounter.  For leaning LibraryLink you can start [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8442/12).

Comment: It is exactly what I would like to do, a NEF importer. TIFF would not be ideal for astrophotographies analyses. Thanks Szabolcs.

Comment: The question I linked to shows you how to extract the data from NEF *without modification*.

Comment: Do you mean using LibrayRaw.org with mathlink, suggested in .CR2 question? I have no idea how implementing it...

Comment: The question I linked to shows you how to extract the data form a NEF file *unmodified* and write it into a TIFF file.  Then you can `Import` the TIFF into Mathematica.  You'll get the image data from the NEF, without demosaicing or any sort of processing, in a Mathematica matrix.  Isn't this what you need?

Comment: I will try this