# Importing a RAW image

Tags: import, warning-messages, image

I have raw images that I can import and view with ImageJ. They are the output of a program which I don't have the source code for, so I'm stuck with the output format.

They are imported as follows with ImageJ:

> Image type: 16 bit Unsigned
>
> Width: 320
>
> Height: 25600
>
> Offset to fist image: 0 bytes
>
> Number of images: 1
>
> Gap Between images: 0 bytes
>
> White is zero unchecked
>
> Little-endian byte order unchecked
>
> Open all files in folder unchecked
>
> use virtual stack unchecked.

Essentially each RAW file is a stack of 100 320 x 256 images.

When I try importing via `Import[]` in *Mathematica*, I get

> ```
> LibraryFunction::rterr: An error with return code -2 was encountered evaluating the function ReadImageRAW.
> ```

> ```
> Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as Raw format.
> ```

I can't seem to find any info on the first error message.

Comment: Maybe the import filters [`"RawBitmap"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/RawBitmap.html)  or [`"BMP"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/BMP.html) with their various options may help. Have a look at their documentation. Since you do not provide example files, you have to try it on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think RawBitmap is getting me closer, but it's giving me Import::coerr: Invalid setting ImageSize -> {320,25600}.

Comment: You may also try `Import[file, "UnsignedInteger16"]` and convert it to an image with `Image`.

Comment: BRILLIANT! "UnsignedInteger16" worked. Thanks so much....it entered everything as a list of all 8 million values so I'll have to do some massaging to get the formatting right, but that's a huge help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
images = Image /@ ArrayReshape[Import[file, "UnsignedInteger16"], {100, 256, 320}];
```

Comment: I have not tested this but I believe that this (or a small variation of it) should do the trick.

Comment: It looks like the width and height were switched, but the output doesn't look quite right. [comparison with imageJ output](https://i.imgur.com/tVn55oJ.jpg) Again, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: images = Image /@ 
  ArrayReshape[Import[file, "UnsignedInteger16"], {100, 256, 320}] ended up being the winner...thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

After some dig in version 13, I found a package that can do this indeed. And I have tried Canon and Sony, so far so good.

```
<< ImageFileTools`
```

Here is a function `` ImageFileTools`Raw`RawGet ``, and its usage is:

```
? ImageFileTools`Raw`RawGet
```

[image]

## Usage

[image]