# Find variable name from DumpSave on a scoped variable

Tags: scoping

I saved an `InterpolationFunction` in a ".mx" files using `DumpSave` on a variable that was scoped by a `Module`. Here is a stripped-down example:

```
Module[{interpolation},
   interpolation=Interpolation[Range[10]];
   DumpSave["interpolation.mx", interpolation];
]
```

Is there a way to find out the variable name, presumably of the form `interpolation$nnn`, of the expression when I `Get` the interpolation? It is not apparent what the variable is when using

```
<<"interpolation.mx"
```

Next time I will not use a `Module` for scoping the save variable, but meantime I'd like to access the saved data and assign it to a new variable.

Comment: Why don't you just use Export?  When just dealing with *data*, I find it really annoying that DumpSave saves variable names.  Export["interp.mx", Interpolation@Range[10]].

Comment: I would solve it using `Block` instead `Module`, besides it, the question is interesting, to see how to work with internal module variables.

Comment: @szabolcs thanks for the tip. I'll use Export next time. Aside from the variable name, are the mx files equivalent? I.e. platform-specific?

Comment: @JxB yep, they're platform specific.  Lately I use `Export["file.mmaz", Compress[expression], "String"]` and `Uncompress@Import["file.mmaz", "String"]` for good performance and platform independence.  The disadvantage is relatively high memory use, and of course it is still slower than MX.  If performance is not an issue (small expressions), just export/import to/from the WDX format.

Comment: For the future you may wish to reference [these save options I outlined](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2008/121).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can open the MX file in an ASCII editor. The variable name is there in plain text (interpolation$511 in my case). The rest is binary gibberish.

So given an `MX` file with a single variable with the `$` suffix, the following expression can be used to access that variable directly:

```
getExpression[filename_] := Module[{a}, 
   ToExpression[(a = StringCases[Import[filename, "Text"], 
   WordCharacter ... ~~ "$" ~~ NumberString][[1]])];
   << (filename);
   ToExpression[a]
  ]
```

E.g.,

```
result = getExpression["interpolation.mx"]
  (* InterpolatingFunction[{{1,10}},<>] *)
```

Evaluating the variable name before reading it with `Get` (or `<<`) seemingly overcomes the `Temporary` attribute discussed in Leonid`s answer. As a (perhaps unwanted) side-effect of the above expression, the original variable remains defined.

This approach could probably be extended to work with multiple variables and expressions in one MX file.

Comment: So I could parse the first n bytes of the file, using ReadList say, to get the name. Nice to know.

Comment: I wonder if manually renaming the variable in a text editor (or with Mma) to remove the $nnn from the variable works, or breaks the file formatting. Will check into it.

Comment: Sjoerd, I added an expression for reassigning the variable directly from Mma. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @JxB Of course not, it's a great addition.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be out of luck (although I will be happy to be proven wrong). This is a rather subtle point, related to the `Temporary` attribute and garbage-collection. I will just share a few observations. First, note that after loading of .mx file on a fresh kernel, the variable is not found anywhere, it is not among the living:

```
<< "interpolation.mx"
names = Flatten[Names[# <> "*"] & /@ Contexts[]];
Flatten@StringCases[names, ___ ~~ "interpolation" ~~ ___]

{"Manipulate`Dump`interpolationToAnimation", 
   "Manipulate`Dump`interpolationToManipulate"}
```

Here is one way to make it persist:

```
Module[{interpolation},
  ClearAll[interpolation];
  interpolation = Interpolation[Range[10]];
  DumpSave["interpolation.mx", interpolation];
]
```

Now it will be found. By using `ClearAll`, I removed the `Temporary` attribute from `interpolation`. Interestingly, another way to do this is to define a `DownValue` rather than an `OwnValue` for it:

```
Module[{interpolation}, 
  interpolation[1] = Interpolation[Range[10]];
  DumpSave["interpolation.mx", interpolation];
]
```

In this case, too, it can be found, since garbage-collection of `Module`-generated variables works differently for `DownValues`.

I can not fully explain why this affected the code for `DumpSave`, which is still inside `Module`. One guess I have is that it gets recorded by `DumpSave` all right, with all attributes, including `Temporary`. Then, when you load it, it probably gets garbage-collected immediately after creation, due to this attribute.

Serializing in this manner using `Module` is also bad (although I am myself guilty of having done this, e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36/file-backed-lists-variables-for-handling-large-data/209#209)) for another reason: `Module`-generated variables are only guaranteed to be unique within a single Mathematica session. It is better to use some custom code to generate variables with names guaranteed to be unique for all sessions (which is easy to do. I recommend to read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860391/how-to-generate-new-unique-name-for-context)).

Comment: Very interesting! Please see my edit to Sjoerd's answer: Evaluating the variable name first is a hack to get around the Temporary issue, I suppose because the variable is then already defined when it is read in? I confess I do not fully understand what is going on.

Comment: @JxB Looks like you are right, good catch. So, apparently, I *was* proven wrong (which is good, at least in this case:-)). I am a bit surprised, because the mechanism that is used in .mx files is quite low-level, it presumably does not communicate with the high-level kernel state, but populates the symbols directly at the low level. So, I'd think it would add the `Temporary` attribute. Perhaps, it prevents immediate garbage collection because it was referenced in the input line, but these are all just guesses.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method, although I don't know how to capture the symbol name programatically...

```
On[General::newsym];
Get["/tmp/test.mx"];
Off[General::newsym];
 (* General::newsym: Symbol a$1772 is new. >> *)
```

Comment: Curious: execute this once, and you get the symbol name; a 2nd time and the message disappears but the symbol gets assigned.