# Save and call matrices with large output in Mathematica

Tags: export

If we have the large matrix

```
A=RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {1000, 1000}];
```

and I need it for further calculation, how can I save it on hard disk and then call for further calculation?  Output is very large and *Mathematica* can not present it, so I can not copy/paste it? Is it possible to print it and then call from hard disk?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Related answer about saving definitions that also extends to data: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2008/121

Answer (score 10):

```
Export["A.wdx", A];
```

will save matrix A in file "A.wdx" on disk. WDX format is binary, compressed, and cross-platform.

Restart Mathematica and evaluate

```
A = Import["A.wdx"];
```

This will read "A" from disk file "A.wdx" and store it in symbol A.

Proceed with your computation.

Comment: yes, but look this problem, if the matirx is in function of variables, when I call after I can not change the variables   In[3]:= A[w1_, w2_] := ( {
    {2 w1[1]*w1[3], 4 w2[5]*w1[6]},
    {3 w1[1]*w2[3], 7 w1[1]*w2[3]}
   } );


In[4]:= Export["A.wdx", A[w1, w2]];


In[5]:= A[w1_, w2_] := Import["A.wdx"];


In[7]:= A[z, z]

Out[7]= {{2 w1[1] w1[3], 4 w1[6] w2[5]}, {3 w1[1] w2[3], 
  7 w1[1] w2[3]}}

Comment: Yes, my answer was limited and was biased towards saving simple data. Still you might get what you want with replacement rules, awkwardly. Say, `With[{ia=Import@"A.wdx"}, A[w1_,w2_] := ReplaceAll[ia, {Global`w1 -> w1, Global`w2 -> w2}];` or some such thing.

Answer (score 5):

If you enter:

```
A >> "savedA.m"
```

then you can get it back with:

```
B=<<savedA`
```

You will get a window, telling you, that a large output was generated. But B now is the same matrix as the A you saved.

Comment: If you include a semi-colon after ``B=<<savedA` `` then the output will be suppressed.

Comment: @rcollyer can you give small example?

Comment: @GeorgeMills sure, but there isn't much beyond what Peter said. Try this, generate a matrix `A = RandomReal[1, {5,5}]`, save it `A >> "saved.m"`, and read it back in ``B=<<saved`; ``. Note, by adding the semi-colon after ``saved` ``, I suppressed its output, and you can verify that it is the same matrix by, in this case, enter `B` in another cell, or if they're to large, `A==B` returns true.

Comment: @rcollyer thank you for many comments. 1) If I want to use A >> "saved.m" how to save somewhere else, for example in another folder and then call from there? 2) It is not necessary to put A==B, I can call with A=<<saved`; after exit from kernel.

Comment: @GeorgeMills 1) You can specify a directory directly in the filename, just like any other program, or specify the directory before hand using [`SetDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDirectory.html). 2) Yes, after you exit the kernel you can then use ``A=<<saved` `` to reload `A`.

Comment: @rcollyer yes but how can I set directory to save on another partition for example D?

Comment: @GeorgeMills how would you normally specify a directory?

Comment: @rcollyer mathematica is installed on C, but I want to Export on D partition, for example D:\George

Comment: @GeorgeMills per the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDirectory.html), `SetDirectory["D:\\George"]` where the `\\ ` is necessary to generate `\ ` in the filename. I'd look at the [file naming tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NamingAndFindingFiles.html), specifically pay attention to the [Composing section](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NamingAndFindingFiles.html#840619645).

Comment: @rcollyer thanks a lot

Comment: @GeorgeMills it appears that the `\ ` was being escaped incorrectly. See my edits above.

Comment: @rcollyer I see, it is clear, thank you very much.

Comment: @rcollyer I used command SetDirectory["D:\\George"] but I got message that I dont have enough space on C during calculation? why? here is location of big file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: @rcollyer you can see here output but I need to use just E, not C

In[27]:= ResetDirectory[]

Out[27]= "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents"

In[29]:= DirectoryStack[]

Out[29]= {}

In[30]:= SetDirectory["E:\\"]

Out[30]= "E:\\"

In[32]:= DirectoryStack[]

Out[32]= {"E:\\", "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents"}

Comment: @GeorgeMills you're misinterpreting what `DirectoryStack` is telling you. The current working directory is on top of the stack, e.g. "E:\\" in your case, and will be the one used. On the other hand, I don't know why your getting the out of space error.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible: use [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DumpSave.html). Warning: not cross-architecture friendly. For your example:

```
In[18]:= A = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {1000, 1000}];

(* for demonstration, save the same matrix A to the variable B for double checking *)
B = A;


(* Dump the variable definition, which includes the variable name, to the file *)
In[20]:= DumpSave[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "a.mx"}], A];


(* Clear the variable A and it's contents from Mathematica's memory. 
Now, the only remnants of A are in the file "a.mx" and in the copied variable B *)
In[21]:= Clear[A]

(* Import and define the variable A again *)
Get[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "a.mx"}]]


(* Check that our important definition of A matches what we defined at the beginning *)
In[23]:= A == B

Out[23]= True
```

You can now use `A` as if you never quit MMA or cleared the variable. So, you can try to calculate the inverse (`Inverse[A]`) or any other legal MMA calculation.

See also the following questions:

- [How do I save a variable or function definition to a file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/save-interpolated-function)
- [File-backed lists/variables for handling large data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36/file-backed-lists-variables-for-handling-large-data)

Comment: this is ok, but I need to save matrix and how to use it for further calculation? In this code to save matrix and then close the Mathematica and open again and just you want for example now Inverse[A] but without repeat calculation, it is already calculated and it is on hard disk, how to do that?

Comment: @GeorgeMills if, instance, the matrix you want saved is the inverse of `A`, then first calculate `Ainv = Inverse[A];` (don't forget the semi-colon), and the use `Ainv` instead of `A` in the above code.

Comment: @GeorgeMills If you use DumpSave, then when you use `Get` or `<<` to import the dumped file, the same symbol is repopulated. Please check the documentation that I linked to. I have also edited my answer to make clear what I am showing.