# How to monitor the progress of Read?

Tags: import, monitoring

I use

```
f = OpenRead["largefile.m"]
x = Read[f];
Close[f];
```

to read in a *Mathematica* expression from a large file `largefile.m` (about 3 GB) and assign it to `x`.  The `Read[f]` step takes very long time.  How to monitor its progress?  BTW, if the file `largefile.m` is larger than `4.1 GB` (as `ls -la` displays), will this approach work?

Comment: Out of curiosity: have you tried using `Get`?

Comment: Also, what does your expression look like and how was it generated?  Could you write it in a format that is more easily read in parts rather than all at once?

Comment: I get `Get:bigfile` error using `Get[]`.

Comment: I could if that's the best approach.  Right now it is `{{...}, {...}}` where `...` is a long sequence of expressions.

Comment: Last year at the Wolfram Tech Conference, I attended a presentation about the various ways to deal with files. You might want to look at the presentation that can be found [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/8025/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am fairly sure that for files of this size, you'll have problems loading them into Mathematica (unless you have truly huge amount of RAM on your machine, but perhaps even in this case). If your file contains newline-terminated strings, or if you otherwise know its structure (types stored there), consider using `ReadList` or `BinaryReadList`. I gave one example in my post [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/a8c9ddbb918bd1b4). In this way, you can attach something like `ProgressIndicator` to it, and monitor the progress. Also, I would recommend to use something similar to  large data framework from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36/file-backed-lists-variables-for-handling-large-data/209#209), to convert the contents of your file / parts of resulting expression, to a file-backed form, since operating on the entire dataset in-memory might not be possible and / or efficient for such huge amounts of data.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using `BinaryReadList` to load reasonably large 100-500MB files and its been working well.

However, I've never had a way to watch the progress. Based @Leonid's answer I hacked together a `ProgressIndicator` for the function.

In my case my large data files consist of sets of 4 32bit (big endian) floats. Here I read the file in 100 steps. Timing is similiar to reading the file all at once.

```
ImportProgress[filename_] := Module[{str, data, n},
  (*open stream*)
  str = OpenRead[filename, BinaryFormat -> True];
  data = {}; n = 1;
  (*display the dynamic progress indicator*)
  Print[ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[n/100]]];
  (*read data*)
  While[n < 100,
   AppendTo[data, 
    BinaryReadList[str, {"Real32", "Real32", "Real32", "Real32"}, 
     Ceiling[FileByteCount[filename]/16/100], ByteOrdering -> +1]];
   n++];
  (*close stream*)
  Close[str];
  (*return the data*)
  data
]

(*read the data*)
data = ImportProgress["R06_14539-v01.pos"];
```

Here is a more elegant alternative using `Monitor` where the `ProgressIndicator` disappears after the file finishes loading:

```
ImportProgressMonitor[filename_] := Monitor[
  Module[{str, data},
   (*open stream*)
   str = OpenRead[filename, BinaryFormat -> True];
   data = {};
   (*read data*)
   n = 1;
   While[n < 100,
    AppendTo[data, 
     BinaryReadList[str, {"Real32", "Real32", "Real32", "Real32"}, 
      Ceiling[FileByteCount[filename]/16/100], ByteOrdering -> +1]];
    n++];
   (*close stream*)
   Close[str];
   data
   ],
  (*monitor the progress*)
  ProgressIndicator[n/100]
]
```