# Dealing with large files

Tags: import, data

I have a *.dat file in which the contents are basically one giant list:

```
{1,2,3,4} {5,6,7,8} {9,10,11,12}
```

and so on. I'd like to read in the first 500 members { } .... { } in to do some computations. The problem is that the file is about 1.5 GB. How does one deal with large files of this type in *Mathematica*?

Comment: I'm interested in this too. When I've been dealing with plain text files, I often use the `split` command in bash. i.e. `split -l 500 data`. [Here's the man page](http://ss64.com/bash/split.html).

Comment: Actually, this SO discussion "Way to deal with large data files in Wolfram Mathematica" looks pretty key for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370570/way-to-deal-with-large-data-files-in-wolfram-mathematica

Comment: split looks useful. But my first 500 sequences are not  neccessarily the first 500 lines. I have no idea what lines they fall on so would need a way of splitting the first 500 { ... } 's which doesn't look like an option

Comment: `cat temp.dat | tr " " "\n" | split -l 500` would be one of many Unix commands. `sed` would also be a good bet.

Comment: thanks cormullion. I was really looking for a mathematica solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, at the moment Mathematica is good only in handle data on memory, what it a problem for big files. I know that they are working to change that, but maybe just in Mathematica 10! So, for now I use bash too.

Comment: [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/209/17) may be relevant.

Comment: I too think this is a duplicate of the question that silvia linked to

Comment: @rm-rf I think Leonid's answer to that question doesn't quite explain how to go from one gigantic file to his system. Perhaps all is needed is that tutorial?

Comment: There was a talk about this in the 2011 conference: "BigData: Demystifying Large Datasets in Mathematica
with Nick Lariviere" http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2011/videos.html

Comment: @rm-rf , I think I agree with tkott. The conference presentation suggests they are working on this for future releases ... let's hope so.

Comment: My framework has not been yet optimized to work with lists where every part is very small but the number of parts is just huge. OTOH, it is relatively straightforward to do. The framework itself need not be modified, since this scenario can be addressed by writing some code on top of it. I will try to work out some example tomorrow.

Comment: For large files I find it nice to monitor the progress of the Read, see my answer at: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4640/how-to-monitor-the-progress-of-read

Answer (score 13):

You can read in the first 500 elements like this:

```
data = ToExpression@ReadList["myfile.txt", Record, 500, RecordSeparators -> " "];
```

On Linux/OS X, items 500 to 1000 can be read in this way:

```
n = 500; m = 1000;

data =ReadList["!cat myfile.txt | tr ' ' '\n'  | head -" <> 
          ToString@m <>" | tail -" <> ToString[m - (n - 1) ]];
```

Assuming your record separator is a space, and that you might want to ignore records which are not of the form, {...}, you could use the following to find records n through m:

```
n = 1; m = 500;

data = ReadList["!cat myfile.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | grep '{.*}' | head -" <> 
  ToString@m <> " | tail -" <> ToString[m - (n - 1) ]];
```

Comment: It would be great if you explain what is the meaning of the argument inside `ReadList` in the second and third examples. I have another separator and I am looking to extract the last record.

Answer (score 6):

Depending  which kind of processing you need, you can try to digest the information as you read, line by line. I wrote this to answer [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43802/sorting-a-large-file/43944#answer-43944) about sorting long files. Its based on [`OpenRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenRead.html) and [`Read`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Read.html). In this case it reads one line, stores only one number from the file and the [`StreamPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPosition.html) in a table for indexing.

```
strR = OpenRead["UnSorted.txt"]

nList = Table[
   With[{sp = StreamPosition[strR], 
     line = Read[strR, {"Word", "Number", "String"}]}, {sp, line[[2]]}]
   , {i, 10^6}
   ];

Close[strR]
```