# Import file size capacity for Mathematica

Tags: import

I am trying to import a large data set (.csv) into *Mathematica*. The data set contains more than 14 million rows, is this something *Mathematica* can handle? If not, what is the maximum capacity? I have tried using the Import command, Kernel still "running" after 20 mins.

Thanks!
CC

Comment: I just tested importing a .csv file with 12.3 million rows and it took about 2.5 min on my PC. However, I have enough RAM available to to it without any trouble. If you are running out of RAM (see e.g. Windows Task-Manager), importing the whole file might get impractical.

Comment: See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14656/18476) and the links therein, if it is necessary for you to read in the file in smaller parts.