# Import data from first/last 100 rows of a file

Tags: import, data

If one wants import data from the first three rows of a file "myfile.data", one can use the command

```
Import["myfile.data",{"Data",{1,2,3},All}];
```

However, if I want import the first 100 rows of the file, is there a quick way besides

```
Import["myfile.data",{"Data",{1,2,3,4,5,....},All}];
```

And what about the case I need import the last 100 rows of the file?

Comment: Related (about large files): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14656/dealing-with-large-files and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36/file-backed-lists-variables-for-handling-large-data/209#209

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To import the first 100 rows of the file you can use

```
Import["myfile.data", {"Data", Range[100]}]
```

and to import the last 100 rows

```
Import["myfile.data", {"Data", -Range[100]}]
```

or

```
Import["myfile.data", {"Data", Range[-100,-1]}]
```

Comment: Warning: this reverses the order of rows. For example if your data has 3 rows and you just use `Import["my file.dat"]` the output will be `{row1,row2,row3}`. But `Import["my file.dat",{"Data",-Range[2]}]` will output `{row3,row2}`

Answer (score 6):

I encourage you to use the following command:

```
Import["file_name.txt", "Table"][[All, ;;100]]
```

It works by default with any structured data, while "Data" doesn't. And what's more important - surprisingly it works **much** faster than importing separated rows or columns - time difference could be the 10-100 times for huge files.

And eventually it's much easier to point what you really want to import with this usual mathematica notation, e.g. take first 5 cols and 100 last rows:

```
Import["file_name.txt", "Table"][[;;5, -100;;]]
```

Comment: This imports the whole file though, which may become inefficient for large files. The OP is not clear on the requirements...

Comment: What means inefficient? and what means large? The point is this command is universal, native for selecting rows/cols and much faster. Say, in case you import something from 10Mb file - it will take 2-4s, while importing as data takes >20s. So for really large files one would wait an hour, instead of a couple of minutes.. Concerning memory consuming - i don't actually know is there really a difference in both commands. Anyway modern computers can easily handle hundreds Mb files, yet files of several gb is surely a different story.

Answer (score 2):

Use the function 'take'

for example

```
list = Import["myfile.data",{"Data",{1,2,3},All}];

Take[list1, 100]
```

> you will get the first hundred values

```
Take[list1, {100,200)]
```

> you wil gett the values hundred until twohundred

Comment: `Take[list,{100,200}]`

you mean?