# How can I validate this dataset in an efficient manner?

Tags: data

I have a large dataset in a single file, consisting of one positive integer per line. The file is more than 20GB in size, and before I do anything with the data I need to validate that everything is as I expect it. For this, I need to check that the number on line $n$ is always strictly greater than the one on line $n-1$.

How can I achieve this in an efficient manner?

This is how I am loading the file into memory:

```
(* Load the data file *)
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Print[DateString[], " - Loading dataset..."]
dataset = ReadList["dataset.txt"];
```

And I can simply access the element at index $i$ with

```
dataset[[i]]
```

Thanks!

---

PS. I am using Mathematica 11.1 and I have a lot of RAM, so space is not an issue.

Comment: Have a look to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60355/10397) that uses `OpenRead` and `Read` to digest data line by line.  Would something like that help?

Comment: @DanielHuber with `d = {4, 2, 3, 4}` your `AllTrue` returns `True` instead of `False`.

Comment: You are right. Here is the correct version: `d = {4, 2, 3, 4}; AllTrue[Transpose[{Rest[d], Most[d]}], 
 Greater @@ ## &]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) and [`And`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/And.html).

```
l1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
And @@ Thread[Rest[l1] > Most[l1]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
l2 = {4, 2, 3, 4};
And @@ Thread[Rest[l2] > Most[l2]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Hope this helps