# UpValues, TagSet and UpSet, what's the difference, when should you use them?

Tags: upvalues

Some of the big mysteries of <strike>Universe</strike> Mathematica for me is the application of UpValues.
I know about [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11435/do-people-actually-use-upvalues) and know the very poor Mathematica documentation on that. I'm very curious to know if someone that not @Leonid uses this too.

Just to get some clue on how it works, I would like to know what's the difference between `TagSet` and `UpSet`. Can I say that `UpSet` is subset of `TagSet`?

For instance, I can say these examples are equivalent.

```
name[alien]^= "Alf"    
alien /: name[alien] = "Alf"
```

In what situations should I apply each case?

Comment: In addition to the answer of @Mr.Wizard, I discussed exactly this issue in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648260/what-does-upvalue-mean-in-mathematica-and-when-to-use-them/6681467#6681467) (last subsection), where it is put in a wider context of `UpValues` in general.

Comment: Tks @LeonidShifrin, It was very helpfull.

Comment: Murta, I see that you did not Accept my answer.  Is there something I can do to make it more satisfactory?

Comment: No! Just forgot. Tks!

Comment: @Leonid Would you please see the comments under my answer?  I am struggling to think of a case where TagSet versus UpSet makes a practical difference, yet I still think I have seen one?  By the way I see you have changed your email address and therefore your Gravatar.  It will be hard to get used to seeing a different icon beside your name.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Re: `UpSet` vs `TagSet` - the only practical difference I am aware of is that `TagSet` is more precise, and will only add an `UpValue` to a symbol you specify, while `UpSet` will add `UpValues` for all symbols at the first level in the l.h.s. of the rule. Re: email change - the funny this is, I didn't change it! Apparently, SE changed the algorithm they use to compute at least some gravatars. I've noticed it and some other users seem to have been affected by it as well (although not all, it seems).

Comment: @Leonid (1) Is there a case where than actually results in a difference in evaluation?  I still have the nagging feeling I have seen one but I can't seem to recreate it.  (2) That's too bad, as I really quite liked your old one.  Did you keep a copy of it?  Maybe set that profile picture manually if you agree with me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard There certainly is a difference.When you execute e.g. `ClearAll[a, b, c, d]; f[a, b, c] ^= d;`, all of the `a,b,c` get `UpValues`, whereas when you execute `ClearAll[a, b, c, d]; a /: f[a, b, c] = d;`, only `a` does. With more complicated patterns involving blanks, it may matter. Generally, you want to be as precise as possible, to not produce extra global rules besides those you need, because they may fire in unforeseen situations. Actually, we pay for locality of overloading based on `UpValues` with making it harder to see why a given rule fired. No reason to make it harder still.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Re: avatar - good idea. Will do that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Apparently, things are worse, and the change happened at the gravatar.com, not SE. They changed the algorithm they use to compute the image. Luckily I had some old .nb file with the old image, although the resolution is quite low. I don't have the time right now to dig deeper and fully reconstruct the avatar programmatically, so I guess that will do for the time being.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`UpSet` and `UpSetDelayed` make multiple assignments:

> **UpSet** associates an assignment with all the distinct symbols that occur either directly as arguments of lhs, or as the heads of arguments of lhs.

```
f[a[__], b[__], c[__]] ^:= "UpValue"

UpValues[a]
UpValues[b]
UpValues[c]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[a[__], b[__], c[__]]] :> "UpValue"}
>
> {HoldPattern[f[a[__], b[__], c[__]]] :> "UpValue"}
>
> {HoldPattern[f[a[__], b[__], c[__]]] :> "UpValue"}
> ```

`TagSet` and `TagSetDelayed` make specific assignments:

```
k /: g[i[__], j[__], k[__]] := "UpValue"

UpValues[i]
UpValues[j]
UpValues[k]
```

> ```
> {}
>
> {}
>
> {HoldPattern[g[i[__], j[__], k[__]]] :> "UpValue"}
> ```

Comment: Is there any meaning to which symbol a rule is assigned to? Maybe who I have to `Clear` to get rid of it?

Comment: @masterxilo I may not understand the question.  In the first example above the rule is bound to all three Symbols `a`, `b`, and `c`, whereas in the second example it is only bound to `k`.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But does using `TagSet` have any observable consequence other than that I have to do `Clear[a,b,c]` in the first example and just `Clear[k]` to get rid of this rule?

Comment: @masterxilo Ah, okay, sorry I didn't understand that the first time.  I believe I have experienced at least one case where there are, but at the moment I can't think of an example.  Let me get back to you on that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard did you eventually think of any example of different use cases between `TagSet` and `UpSet`?

Comment: @glS No, I never did.  Leonid Shifrin might be able to give an example as he appears to think through such details systematically.

Comment: @glS I think perhaps the case I was remembering was more simple that I had recalled, and I kept dismissing the simple example as trivial.  However I think it is likely that the example *at the time* did not seem trivial to me which is why I have the memory of it being more profound.  Anyway a *simple example* of a difference is:  `f[a_Integer, b_foo] ^:= bar` which throws a *UpSetDelayed::write: Tag Integer in f[a_Integer,b_foo] is Protected* message, whereas `foo /: f[a_Integer, b_foo] := bar` does not.  Both still create an UpValue on `foo` successfully however.

Comment: @masterxilo You might also find the comment above of interest.  It still does not seem like a satisfying example of a difference as a simple `Quiet` makes them equivalent again, but it is the only difference, trivial or not, that I can think of.