# Access curated or locally stored data with curated data functions?

Tags: curated-data, upvalues

Say I have a toy package, something like:

```
BeginPackage["myPackage`"]
plotSomeData::usage = "plotFinancialData[symbol]... some usage language";
Begin["`Private`"]
plotSomeData[symbol_]:= DateListPlot[FinancialData[symbol, All]]
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

This should work fine, nothing particularly complicated here.

So now, I'd like to extend the `FinancialData[]` function embedded in the package to enable it to seamlessly access *non-Wolfram curated data* stored locally on my computer.

I could rewrite the package and set up some conditional code that would replace `FinancialData[]` with `Import[]`, something like:

```
plotSomeData[symbol_] := DateListPlot[
  Which[
   symbol == "xyz", Import[pathAndFileName],
   symbol != "xyz", FinancialData[symbol, All]
   ]]
```

But, in my case, that would mean rewriting a bunch of perfectly good packges, so I'd like another solution.  Some of the questions and answers such as:

[What is a paclet?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/what-is-a-paclet/1664#1664)

[UpValues TagSet and UpSet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18410/upvalues-tagset-and-upset-whats-the-difference-when-should-a-use-each)

have me wondering if another more elegant way exists to do this.

Could, for instance, one extend the paclet information for a set of curated data?

I've used `TagSet` before to do things like define how to calculate the `CDF` of a custom distribution, but I don't see a clear way to use it to enable a curated data function to recognize the location of a data symbol it doesn't already know.

`SetOptions` doesn't seem like the thing either.

`UpVales` and `UpSet` might do it, but I don't see it yet.

Ideally, I'd simply like to extend a curated data function to recognize the location of a data symbol it doesn't already know and thereby enable it to get the newly identified data.

Best if I can do this outside of the packages I already have.

Any ideas?

(The tags I have on this question could use some improvement, if anyone has some better ideas.)

Comment: You can't add rules to `FinancialData`, since it is `Locked`. As you mentioned yourself, `UpValues` can help. You can define a given symbol as `sym/: FinancialData[sym,...]:=...`, where you can insert on the r.h.s. the definition you want.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin -- I think I understand.  The r.h.s would become my Import[pathAndFileName].  That should enable me to do additional statements for other symbols that would correspond to their own data sets?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin -- Certainly worthy of an accepted answer in my opinion.  If you want to post it, you've got my vote.  - Thx.

Comment: No time for it at the moment, alas. Will do when I get some window, unless someone does that first. Also, feel free to post your own answer based on the hints I gave, and accept that.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin -- You have a generous spirit.  Nice to have you in the world.

Comment: @Leonid and Jagra: it's time for an answer to this one, don't you think?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree, but sadly, today is very bad for me. I might be able to do that tomorrow, the main problem is not to forget about it (I have tons of things to do these days).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard -- I agree too, but my life has me in the wilds of North Ontario this week with no access to Mathematica.  Hope to tackle this when I return to civilization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Mr.Wizard asked, "...it's time for an answer, don't you think?".

I forgot about this question, but after year it occurred to me to formulate an answer following @LeonidShifin suggestions:

First get some test data:

```
testData = FinancialData["GE", "Jan. 1, 2000"][[1 ;; 10]];
dataFile = "/Users/jagra/Data.test.csv";
Export[dataFile, testData, "CSV"];
```

Apply `UpValues`

```
sym /: FinancialData[sym] := Last[Import[dataFile]][[2]]
sym /: FinancialData[sym, All] := Import[dataFile]
sym /: FinancialData[sym, date_String] := Module[{data, pos},
  data = Import[dataFile];
  pos = Position[data, date];
  data[[Flatten[pos][[1]]]]]

FinancialData[sym]
FinancialData[sym, All]
FinancialData[sym, "{2000, 1, 4}"]


32.45

{{{2000, 1, 3},32.24},{{2000, 1, 4},30.95},{{2000, 1, 5},30.89},{{2000, 1, 6},31.31},{{2000, 1, 7},32.52},{{2000, 1, 10},32.5},{{2000, 1, 11},32.56},{{2000, 1, 12},32.67},{{2000, 1, 13},33.04},{{2000, 1, 14},32.45}}

{{2000, 1, 4},30.95}
```

This doesn't show all possible configurations for getting data (and even has a shortcut in using "{2000, 1, 4}") , but I think it demonstrates the flexibility of the approach.