# Edit built in symbol

Tags: curated-data, customization, assignment

I would like to add new attributes to built in symbols (e.g. `ElementData` or `PolyhedraData`) so that I can still call the symbol in the same way (e.g. `ElementData["name","property"]`) but now with a new, user-added property. Is that possible?

Comment: Related: [access-curated-or-locally-stored-data-with-curated-data-functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23427/access-curated-or-locally-stored-data-with-curated-data-functions)

Comment: This is difficult to achieve, mainly because the arguments are strings so that it's not possible to directly use the approach mentioned by @SjoerdC.deVries. Maybe the cleanest way would be to define `myElementData` such that it calls `ElementData` and adds new definitions only when that doesn't return a built-in result. Strings with built-in meanings have proliferated in recent versions, and `UpValues` don't work on them; also this makes it harder to do syntax-checking (highlighting) in complicated commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not state that you wished to avoid making additional assignments upon a `` System` `` Symbol, therefore that is a natural approach and it is possible using [`Unprotect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unprotect.html) since `ElementData` is not [`Locked`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Locked.html), and it appears to work correctly here:

```
Unprotect[ElementData];
ElementData["Carbon", "Resonance"] = 42;
ElementData["Phlebotinum", "AtomicWeight"] = 666;
Protect[ElementData];
```

Now:

```
ElementData["Tungsten", "ThermalConductivity"]
ElementData["Carbon", "Resonance"]
ElementData["Phlebotinum", "AtomicWeight"]
```

> ```
> 170. W/(m K)
>
> 42
>
> 666
> ```

If this this is not acceptable please explain why, or if it fails please give me an example.

---

Based on the comments I think you need something more advanced than the naive assignments above.  Instead your problem is similar to:

- [Making a symbol's new definitions be tried before all previously defined ones](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2793/121)

Because more general patterns will not result in your own definitions being tried first.

I propose keeping your own element rules in a separate list and using a single DownValue on `ElementData` to inject them.  To accomplish this the DownValue (definition rule) must be placed at the beginning of the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html) list so that it has priority, and it should be placed there after `ElementData` is first run to preload the base definitions.

```
ElementData[] (* preload *);
Unprotect[ElementData];
PrependTo[
  DownValues @ ElementData,
  HoldPattern[p_ElementData /; $modElemData =!= True] :>
   Block[{$modElemData = True}, Replace[Unevaluated[p], elementRules]]
];
Protect[ElementData];
```

We now define `elementRules` however we like:

```
elementRules =
  {
   _["Carbon", "AtomicWeight"] -> "Fat",
   _["Phlebotinum", "AtomicWeight"] -> 666,
   _[1 | "H" | "Hydrogen", "Wobble"] -> 0.37,
   _[_, "Charge"] -> "Matter"
  };
```

Note that `_` is used as a proxy for `ElementData`; this prevents unwanted evaluation  and a more specific pattern is not necessary as these rules will only be applied to `ElementData` expressions.  (Add [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dispatch.html) for performance if you have many rules.)

Now the rules are applied before any built-in ones:

```
ElementData["Titanium", "Density"]
ElementData["Carbon", "AtomicWeight"]
ElementData["H", "Wobble"]
ElementData["Gold", "Charge"]
```

> ```
> 4507. kg/(m)^3
>
> "Fat"
>
> 0.37
>
> "Matter"
> ```

Comment: That is what I have been doing but ideally I would like all definitions of "atom" to share such "property" so that not only `ElementData["Carbon", "Resonance"]` works but also `ElementData["C", "Resonance"]`. Not sure there is a way to easily link them, though, without a manual `clone`

Comment: @PFD So you mean you want e.g. `ElementData["anything", "Foo"]` to return `bar`?

Comment: Yes as long as the value `bar` becomes available for other instances of `anything`. For ex. `ElementData[1, "Name"]` returns the same as `ElementData["H", "Name"]` or `ElementData["Hydrogen", "Name"]` = `hydrogen`.

Comment: @PFD Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @mr-wizard, very elegant. And to generalize your Hydrogen example: `_ElementData[i | ToString[ElementData[i, "Abbreviation"]] | ToString[ElementData[][[i]][[2]]] , "Wobble"] -> 0.4` where i is the element number. That will do.

Comment: @PFD I'm glad you like my answer.  However note that `_ElementData[__]` *will not match* `ElementData[1,2]` but only something like `ElementData[1][2]`.  Use merely `_` as the head of the pattern as I did in my answer.