# What is the point of tagset /:?

Tags: assignment

I'm teaching myself Mathematica and came across [tagset](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet.html).

So I followed the example in the link, but seem to be missing the point. All of the below give me the same answer after assignment: that `area[square]` equals `s^2`.

```
area /: area[square] = s^2

square /: area[square] = s^2

area[square] = s^2
```

So why have 3 ways of doing things?

Comment: `Upvalues` are quite important for defining custom (abstract) data types: ["*`Upvalues` are an indispensable tool to overload various functions (built-in or user-defined) on custom data types. They provide the only safe way to do that, in fact.*"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110003/764)

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11435/do-people-actually-use-upvalues -- Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18410/upvalues-tagset-and-upset-whats-the-difference-when-should-a-use-each

Comment: Another use is to attach the definition of a `Derivative` of a function `f` to the symbol `f` instead of to `Derivative`, so that `Clear[f]` clears the derivative definition. (E.g. `f /: Derivative[1][f] := #^2 &;

D[f[x], x]`)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Any reason not to mark this question as a duplicate of the ones you linked?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I guess not. So voted. Lately I post a comment as a suggestion to allow debate before committing a vote. Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2514/should-duplicates-be-closed-any-more)?

Comment: @Michael Yes I had, and I reread it again now.  I *think* I understand your position, but don't see the harm in one-vote-closing; it's why that feature exists after all.  If you don't have the energy to go dupe-hunting I understand simply posting a quick answer and I've done it myself often enough.  But if you *do* know of a duplicate I still think it is *valuable* to mark it as such.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TagSet` is useful for assigning `UpValues` to symbols. These are often used to make built-in functions do something different for specific symbols. For example, suppose I defined a symbolic square with the symbol `square` and I want to compute its area by doing this:

```
square[4]^2
```

> 16

This is how you can do this with `TagSet`:

```
ClearAll[square]
square /: square[length_]^2 := length^2;
square[4]^2
```

Note that this does not work with a normal assignment:

```
In[85]:= ClearAll[square2]
square2[length_]^2 := length^2;
square2[4]^2
```

> During evaluation of In[85]:= SetDelayed::write: Tag Power in square2[length_]^2 is Protected.
>
> Out[87]= square2[4]^2

This is because the assignment `square2[length_]^2 := ...` tries to assign a `DownValue` to `Power`:

```
Hold[square2^2 := area[square]] // FullForm
```

> Hold[SetDelayed[Power[square2, 2], area[square]]]

Since `Power` is a protected symbol, you can't assign values to it like this. By using `TagSet`, you assign an `UpValue` to `square`, which overrides the default behavior of `Power`, since upvalues have a higher priority than `DownValues`:

```
In[91]:= UpValues[square]

Out[91]= {HoldPattern[square[length_]^2] :> length^2}
```

**edit**

As pointed out in the [link in the comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues/127#127), there are some subtleties about the evaluation order you should be aware off if you really want to use `UpValues` in your code. It's good to be aware of those.

Comment: +1. One comment though. *"`UpValues` have a higher priority than `DownValues`"* - when written in this way, this statement is somewhat misleading, since it suggests comparison for these `...Values` for the same symbol, while it is only true when we talk about `UpValues` attached to inner expression's head vs. `DownValues` of the outer head. I have devoted a few paragrhaphs to explain the meaning of this statement in more detail in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127) (section *"DownValues vs UpValues: Order of evaluation"*), specifically to avoid this confustion.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks for linking that answer. I was aware that there are some subtleties involved with that, but I thought that for an answer like this it was probably not worth it to bury the main story in details. Still, it's very good to have a resource for further reading. I'll include the link in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

As an addendum to Sjoerd's great answer, I would simply like to show a use case for defining a custom [data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) and then using `TagSet` to create what is called an [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type).

In many cases we would like to be quite sure, that our data have a certain form (e.g. do some *type checking*). Mathematica nicely supports this by constraining patterns to those with a certain `Head` (see [Specifying Types of Expressions in Patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecifyingTypesOfExpressionInPatterns.html)):

```
func[ input_myDataType ] :=  ...
```

Here, `func` will only accept expressions that have the form `myDataType[ e1, e2, ... ]`. Having [*constructed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)) any `myDataType` "object" in a reliable way (e.g. from basic inputs with very concise and strict pattern matching restrictions) greatly helps to prevent errors down the road.

While [Associations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) are really great for building composite data types, it will usually not suffice to simply check an expression for the head being `Association` - instead, we have to look at least at some key(s) as well to be certain.

But, we may (with a maybe negligible disadvantage regarding speed) combine data type filtering using an expression's `Head` with the flexibility of associations:

```
data = Association @@ Table[ "Key" <> ToString @ i -> i , {i,1000} ];    
myData = myDataType[ data ];
myDataType/: (key_String)[ data_myDataType ] := Lookup[ data[[1]], key ]
```

Now, we can elegantly write:

```
"Key500" @ myData
(* 500 *)
```

Note, that this is really quite close to *object-oriented programming*:

```
class/: method[ instance_class, args___ ] := "What to do"
```

Instead of overloading some method to work with a new class, we can simply tie the method to the definition of the class as an `UpValue`.

Comment: @mchen To better understand these ideas I suggest to read [Associating Definitions with Different Symbols](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AssociatingDefinitionsWithDifferentSymbols.html) in the documentation.