# Defining a custom Plus for a specific class of arguments

Tags: function-construction

I'm trying to develop an domain-specific language with *Mathematica*. I want to define a customized behavior for the `Plus` function when applied to my data.

For simplifying the problem, let's say that my custom data is of a list of associations.

```
Unprotect[Plus];
Plus[x_List, y_List] := Join[x, y] // Merge[Total]
Protect[Plus];
```

Then,

```
{<|"a" -> 1|>, <|"b" -> 2|>} + {<|"a" -> 2|>}
```

gives the correct answer with an error message.

> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {<|a -> 1|>, <|b -> 2|>} + {<|a -> 2|>} cannot be combined. >>
>
> ```
> <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 2|>
> ```

How can I avoid the error message? I suspect an evaluation control problem, but I can't find any clues to solve it.

Comment: Interesting that an error is not thrown with using an undefined infix operator such as `CirclePlus`

Comment: If you put `DownValues` on `Plus` you will slow down anything that has a `Plus` in it, by a considerable amount. Either define a new operation `myNewListPlus`, or do this with `UpValues`.

Comment: @bobthechemist I guess M tried to evaluate the expr with its own definition first and then with my definition. It's a blind guess. I'm learning M.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you for the advise. I didn't know about the performance. However, I want it to have a simple and seamless syntax. Could you explain more about using UpValues? I know the syntax and usage but I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: I wonder if [people really use upvalues](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11435/7167)?

Comment: @bobthechemist In my case, I want to do something like this...`Plus[x_?MyDataQ, y_?MyDataQ]^:=myPlus[x,y]`. But it is not possible. However, the link is useful. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I now realize `UpValues` is not a good idea in this specific situation. The reason is that they would be put on `List`, which is another object so critical to internals that it will likely mess up performance.

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cause

As Junho Lee explains this is due to the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) attribute of `Plus` which takes effect before other rules.

[The Standard Evaluation Procedure](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure.html) tutorial says:

> As soon as the Wolfram System has evaluated the head of an expression,
>   it sees whether the head is a symbol that has attributes. If the
>   symbol has the attributes `Orderless`, `Flat`, or `Listable`, then
>   immediately after evaluating the elements of the expression the
>   Wolfram System performs the transformations associated with these
>   attributes.

Here is a simple example with a user defined function:

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable];
f[a__] := foo[a]

f[{1, 2, 3}, 4]
```

> ```
> {foo[1, 4], foo[2, 4], foo[3, 4]}
> ```

Notice how threading was performed *before* the definition was applied.

### Proposal

You wrote: "*I want it to have a simple and seamless syntax.*"

I propose using one of the [undefined Operators](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html) such as [`CirclePlus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePlus.html):

```
CirclePlus[x : {__Association}, y : {__Association}] := Join[x, y] // Merge[Total]
```

Now:

```
﻿{<|"a" -> 1|>, <|"b" -> 2|>} ⊕ {<|"a" -> 2|>}
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 2|>
> ```

The character `⊕` is entered with <kbd>Esc</kbd>`c+`<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

The message is due to `Listable` attribute. I guess that the `Listable` process call `Thread`.  If you get rid of this attribute, do like this.

```
Unprotect[Plus];
Plus[x_List, y_List] := Join[x, y] // Merge[Total]
Protect[Plus];

ClearAttributes[Plus, Listable]
```

Have try this.

```
{<|"a" -> 1|>, <|"b" -> 2|>} + {<|"a" -> 2|>}
```

> `<|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 2|>`

But if you maintain the attribute, suggest to use `Off[Thead::tdlen]` of message off as @mete said.

Comment: Given that the listability of `Plus` is a fundamental property in *Mathematica* this modification is *highly* inadvisable, nevertheless I agree with your analysis so +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the message off by doing

```
Off[Thread::tdlen]
```

You are not really avoiding it, just putting under the carpet

Comment: Maybe my english was wrong but I didn't mean this. Thanks,anyway.