# Replacing product of functions wih another function

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have a function which depends on `w`,`x`,`y`,`z`. Let me call it `Φ[w, x, y, z]`. I want to square `(a Φ[w1, x1, y1, z1] + b Φ[w2, x2, y2, z2])` and in the expansion I want to replace the product of the two `Φ` expressions with another function `Ψ[w1, x1, y1, z1, w2, x2, y2, z2]`. I will define only `Ψ`, not `Φ`. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far, to clarify the question?  Did you try `ReplaceAll` ?

Answer (score 6):

One possibility that comes to mind is using [UpValues (nice SE post explaining it)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11435/do-people-actually-use-upvalues).

If I understand you right, you basically want this:

```
phi /: phi[a__] * phi[b__] = psi[a, b]
phi /: phi[a__]^2 = psi[a, a]
```

where you basically tell *Mathematica* that if `phi` appears anywhere, it should look in what context it is -- i.e., in a product or a square -- and replace it by the appropriate expression on the right side of the assignment.

This will be global, so anytime you write phi, *Mathematica* will check for context (which introduces an overhead) but you won't have to think about applying rules. (Which can also be dangerous if you use phi for different functions).