# How does this `Tagset` /: defined function work?

Tags: function-construction, vector-calculus

This came up in an assignment problem.

I am tasked to use

1)
    `▽ /: ▽[f_] := {D[f, x], D[f, y], D[f, z]}`

2)
    `▽ /: ▽ · {fx_, fy_, fz_} := D[fx, x] + D[fy, y] + D[fz, z]`

and

3)
    `▽ /: Cross[▽, {fx_, fy_, fz_}] := {D[fz, y] - D[fy, z], D[fx, z] - D[fz, x], D[fy, x] - D[fx, y]}`

to show that

```
▽[a.b] == Cross[a, Cross[▽, b]] + Cross[b, Cross[▽, a]] + a.▽[b] + b.▽[a]
```

is true.

However, I am unable to figure out how the given operators work.
I understand that the given operators are defined functions.
However, treating the given operators as though they were a defined function -in fact they are!- doesn't work.

For instance, referring to 1) and trying to evaluate a scalar number "1":

```
▽ /: ▽[1]
```

*Mathematica* returns nothing.

Comment: Read these instructions: [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and reformat your question. For Greek / special characters you can use [Halirutan's SE tool](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor) or [the Steampiano converter](http://steampiano.net/msc/).

Comment: @MarcoB I think the necessary changes has been done

Comment: Thank you for editing the question. You don't need to repeat the `TagSet` when using the function. Try evaluating just `▽[1]`: it will return `{0, 0, 0}`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do people actually use UpValues?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11435/do-people-actually-use-upvalues)

Comment: @MarcoB 
In the given question tasked, f is a vector. However, inputting an arbitrary vector to be acted on by the operator results in a matrix-one should be getting a scalar instead.
Am I misunderstanding the operators?

Comment: @Physkid Give us an example of arbitrary input, the output you get, and the output you would expect instead. Edit that into the question.

Comment: @MarcoB 
I apologise. I input something different instead and arrive at a false conclusion. That was my mistake.
I'm still having a bit of trouble trying to figure how to approach this question. 
Would it be necessary to define the vector "a" and vector "b"?

Comment: Note that for 1) the TagSet is not necessary. @Physkid I would say yes, try `{a -> Array[a[x, y, z], 3], b -> Array[b[x, y, z], 3]}`... (make sure you `Hold` the expression, apply the replacements and only then `ReleaseHold`).