# How was Nothing implemented?

Tags: list-manipulation, implementation-details

How was `Nothing` implemented in Wolfram language at the language level? 
For example, `{a, b, Nothing, c, d, Nothing}` will return `{a, b, c, d}`. How does `Nothing` here affect the `List`? I can't see what mechanism can achieve this effect.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok, I failed to find a duplicate so here is my comment:

I don't know how `Nothing` is internally implemented but you can do something like this with `UpValues`:

```
nothing /: {a___, nothing, b___} := {a, b}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would speculate that the internal implementation might build upon `Sequence[]`. Consider

```
{a, b, Sequence[], c, d, Sequence[]}
```

which evaluates to

```
{a, b, c, d}
```

However, to use that in replacement rules, you need to wrap it in `Unevaluated` like this

```
{a, b, c, d} /. c -> Unevaluated[Sequence[]]
```

which gives

```
{a,b,d}
```

P.S. I found out about `Sequence[]` from some answer on this site some years ago, but I don't remember which one exactly. I use it since then in all my codes, so that I consider `Nothing` just some sort of syntactic sugar (which is also not compatible with older Mathematica versions).

Comment: 1) But why do you think so? `Sequence` does not care about being in a `List` or not: `h[a, Sequence[]]`. 2) you don't need `Unevaluated` because `Rule` is `SequenceHold`.

Comment: Regarding 1) I just fail to see much sense for using `Nothing` where one can usually get the same effect with `Sequence[]` (that is also backward compatible). Is there perhaps an example, where one can achieve something really useful with `Nothing` that you can't get with `Sequence`? As for 2), you are of course right, `Rule` is a wrong example here. But `Map` and `If` do not have the `HoldSequence` attribute, so there `Unevaluated` is actually needed (AFAIK): `Map[If[# === a, Sequence[],#]&,{a,b,c,d}]` vs. `Map[If[# === a, Unevaluated[Sequence[]],#]&,{a,b,c,d}]`.

Comment: Well, I guess my answer is anyhow offtopic, since the original question was really about the implementation. I just wanted to point out that (IMHO) `Nothing` is not really needed to achieve the same effect. I probably should have stated it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Ad ad 1) It is shorter to write `If[cond, sth, Nothing]` than `Unevaluated @ Sequence[]`, and more readable than `##&[]` so it is not like a long awaited solution but rather a small feature to make code cleaner. I didn't face a use case where `Nothing` left in other heads would be very useful but maybe someone did.