# Understanding TagSetDelayed

Tags: upvalues

I was reading [What is the distinction between DownValues, UpValues, SubValues, and OwnValues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues) and I started to be confused with the part "Upvalues" of the first answer.

Some of my confusion comes from the fact I don't really understand TagSetDelayed, I took a look at mathematica documentation but I'm more confused.

May I have a simple explanation of how it works with simple examples ?

The documentation take the example :

```
g /: f[g[x_]] := fg[x]
{f[g[2]], f[h[2]]}

{fg[2], f[h[2]]}
```

So, allright it means that when I call f[g[2]] it will be replaced by fg[2]
But it seems to be more general as they do f[h[2]]. What happens in this case ? h is replacing g in the expression then we have f[h[2]].

Well I don't really get what is happening and how it can be usefull

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648260/what-does-upvalue-mean-in-mathematica-and-when-to-use-them) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11435/do-people-actually-use-upvalues) could be helpful

Comment: Is your question why wasn't `h` case converted?