# Can UpValues (as well as other "*Values") always be converted to DownValues?

Tags: upvalues, downvalues

As [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11435/do-people-actually-use-upvalues) has discussed, `UpValues` are certainly useful, and as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648260/what-does-upvalue-mean-in-mathematica-and-when-to-use-them) has discussed, `g /: f[g[x_]] := h[x]` is not equivalent to `f[g[x_]] := h[x]`, but that's not the point. It appears that other languages don't provide the alleged `UpValues` in general.
So, my question is: can  `UpValues` and other `*Values` all **always** be converted to `DownValues` (rather than asking for those distinctions)?   And if not, does this mean that one can *never* implement the same functionalities in MMA's competitive products (like Maple and Mathics)?

Comment: Sometimes symbols to which you want to attach `DownValues` are `Protected` and/or `Locked`.

Comment: Does it make sense to ask if `OwnValues` and `SubValues` can be converted to `DownValues`?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but... [section 9.7 of the Maple Programming Guide](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ProgrammingGuide/Chapter09) shows an example that essentially uses up-values.

Comment: @JasonB. ```(*x=.;*)Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[Global`x]``` gives ```Language`DefinitionList[x->{OwnValues->{},SubValues->{},UpValues->{},DownValues->{},NValues->{},FormatValues->{},DefaultValues->{},Messages->{},Attributes->{Protected}}]```; I think that other values are as important as downvalue.

Comment: @user688486 - I don't know what that printed mess is supposed to add to the discussion.  Say I define an `OwnValue` via `x=14`.  What does it mean to "convert" that to a `DownValue`?

Comment: @JasonB. Sorry for confusion. I listed them here before, for I found that other "*Values" are often listed together with ```DownValues``` and ```UpValues```. However, the main focus of attention is simply upvalue and downvalue, so I have edited my problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but a comment with image.

Certainly the `UpValues` can be converted to `DownValues` and the `SubValues` can be curried to `DownValues` manually, but then we mess up the bindings of symbols.

Before embracing associations I usually used the `DownValues`, `UpValues` and `SubValues` to store data.

Although there is no native OOP in Mathematica, we can treat certain symbols e.g. `class` as class like,

```
masterOf[class]^=...
servantOf[class]^=...
isProtected[class]^=...
class["some instance"]=...
...
```

For example, the GR packages `` xAct`* `` use this method to manage relations between geometric objects
[image]

So `UpValues` is quite useful to make the dependencies of symbols more structured.

But with the more powerful `Association` and the interface `Dataset`, we can free ourselves from the cumbersome symbol management.