# Can Mathematica functions have static variables?

Tags: programming, function-construction

In `C`, one can have variables that are declared `static`. These are not re-initialized every single time a function is called. I.e.:

```
int f(int inc)
{
    static int x = 0;
    return x += inc;
}
```

Then `f(0);f(1);f(2);` will return `0`,`1`, and `3`. Is this possible in *Mathematica*?

One use that immediately comes to mind is having a compiled function stored as a static variable for use in a ME function.

Comment: Why not use global variables? If you afraid that other functions might change it, you can add `Protect` to its attributes and only unprotect it inside your `Module`.

Comment: It looks like this is a duplicate of [Modules that initialize themselves on first call](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11655)

Comment: See also the answer by @Leonid to  [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/245)

Comment: @Mark Providing another avenue to find solutions is exactly the role that duplicate questions play; if this one is closed it will still serve as a signpost to the original.

Comment: @rm-rf Sort of - my question doesn't pertain to `Module` in particular however.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Yes; I suppose. Although, that's not stylistically pleasing enough - it introduces a new variable (which will not/should not be documented) and takes up the namespace with high coupling to the function itself. Others may also `Unprotect` it. I suppose along the same vein someone could alter `field$...` in my solution, though.

Comment: Generally I agree with you, though we are talking about _Mathematica_ here. In _Mathematica_, the elegance and pragmatism of C cannot and should not be persued. Honestly, I dont't know about any built-in _Mathematica_ function that uses static variables in any of the proposed ways below, though I do know about many that affect global variables during runtime (like `$Directory`, `$Context` etc.), so I would say this is the common _Mathematica_-way.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I'm sure that built-in functions, if they do use, as I mentioned in the question, compiled code, just have the call to those functions hard-coded in them.

Comment: That is indeed possible for hardcoded built-ins, but at the moment, user-compiled code cannot use static global variables, see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31171/89).

Comment: I'll bet that `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]` uses an internal static variable.  The usual way to generate a Gaussian random variable is to generate _two_ of them (finding a point inside a unit circle).  Then you keep the second one in a static variable for the next call, which makes it twice as fast.  I just tried rolling my own that does that, and used `CompilationTarget->"C"` on it to be able to compare execution times.  Its execution time for two million random variables is the same as the execution time for the internal `Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {2000000}]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18799/121

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use a context.  I.e.:

```
f`x = 0;
f[inc_] := f`x += inc

f[0]
0

f[1]
1

f[2]
3
```

It is a global (though not in the Global context), using a namespace to protect it from inadvertent change.

You can also protect it inside a `Module[]`:

```
Module[{x},
 x = 0;
 f[inc_] := x += inc;
 ]

f[0]
0

f[1]
1

f[2]
3
```

It's still a global though:

```
?? f
Global`f
f[inc$_]:=x$274+=inc$

x$274
3
```

I don't know if there's a way to make a completely private, invisible static variable, like in C.  I tried `BeginPackage[]`, and it doesn't do anything magical either.  Everything made in the package is accessible from outside.

This is kind of an issue in my mind.  If I distribute a package, users of the package can make use of internal states that I do not intend to be used.  If I distribute a new version with different internal states, it will break the code of those users.  Yes, we can say that they were asking for it.  However in other languages, this can be prevented entirely.  Unless I've missed how to make invisible internal states in Mathematica.

Comment: I suppose if one really wants to mimic private scope then they would use `Protect` and `Unprotect` as István Zachar suggests. Also I think I'll use the context method instead of Module from now on because at least that global variable is clearly related to that function, whereas `Module`'s temporary that is alive past its scope sort of looks messy and seems more prone to error.

Comment: That's half of what private should mean.  The other half is not being able to see or get the value of the private variable.

Comment: Right, but that half is strictly related to aspects of programming design that are really more relevant to languages that have the `static` keyword. For _Mathematica_ I suppose that the purpose of private is that of safety mainly.

Answer (score 3):

I think that there is at least one workaround, but it would be nice to see if anyone else has thought of anything. I got this answer from playing around with [celtschk's answer to one of my OOP in MMA questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13360/do-objects-in-mathematica-have-to-be-declared).

```
Module[{generator},
 generator[] :=
  Module[{field = 0},
    (* Function goes here, should be pure *)
    field += # &];
 increasing = generator[];
 ]
```

Evaluating this definition resets the "static" variable in `increasing`.

```
increasing[0]
(* 0 *)
increasing[1]
(* 1 *)
increasing[2]
(* 3 *)
```

Comment: @Nasser right, and since it's just a function (of which there should only ever be one instance, the generator is temporary and the object name is global. But for this specific purpose I think Mark Adler's way has better style (and avoids temporaries).