# Making a NestList with a slot argument of arbitrary length

Tags: functions, function-construction

This is an extension to a previous question that I never fully answered, but have been better able to define with some new reading (see other question here: [Implementing delay in NestList?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155861/implementing-delay-in-nestlist))

I would like to implement Buchner's Logistic map with delayed feedback:

```
x(n+1)=(1-K)r*x(n)[1-x(n) + K x(n-k)
```

where K is the feedback gain and k is the feedback delay. Very helpfully, the above system can be rewritten as a set of k+1 coupled iterated functions with no delay, i.e. (below as equations, not mathematica code):

```
x1(n+1)=(1-K)r*x1(n)[1-x1(n) + K x2(n)
x2(n+1)=x3(n)
x3(n+1)=x4(n)
...
xk(n+1)=x1(n)
```

So with a fixed value of k, I can rewrite the system such as:

```
Module[{K = .2, r = 3.6, x1 = 1, x2 = 1, x3 = 1, x4 = 1, x5 = 1},
 dataNest = NestList[
   {(1 - K) r #[[1]] (1 - #[[1]]) + K #[[2]], 
     #[[3]],
     #[[4]],
     #[[5]],
     #[[1]]} &,
   {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5},
   100];
 ListLinePlot[dataNest[[All, 1]]]
 ]
```

(The above case should show an oscillatory solution. These kinds of systems are used to examine chaos and nonlinear dynamics.)

I would like to rewrite the above block such that I can specify k and construct the NestList of the appropriate length. I suspect this is not too tricky, but pure functions and slot syntax are still a bit confusing to me.

I think the only tricky bit is the list that goes into NestList, because of the pure function. Creating the initial conditions vector seems easier. So I need a list where the first entry is `(1 - K) r #[[1]] (1 - #[[1]]) + K #[[2]]`, the 2nd through k entries are `[[3]]` through `[[k+1]]` and the k+1 entry is `[[1]]`. Would some syntactically gifted residents offer some guidance?

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a good place for a recursive definition. Just set the desired delay to `j`. The `If` is used to set the initial conditions (to all 1, as in the OPs example), otherwise it defines the recursion.

```
Clear[x]; k = 0.2; r = 3.6; j = 5;
x[n_] := x[n] = If[n < j, 1, (1 - k) r*x[n - 1] (1 - x[n - 1]) + k x[n - j]];
ListLinePlot[x[#] & /@ Range[100]]
```

[image]

You could equally well define the initial conditions by formula or from a list by embedding this in the `If`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a straight-forward way, in which you don't even have to specify `k` explicitly. Instead, it's automatically "detected" via the length of the initial condition list.

```
buchnerLogisticMap[K_, r_, init_] := NestList[
   Join[{(1 - K) r #[[1]] (1 - #[[1]]) + K #[[2]]}, #[[3 ;;]], {#[[1]]}] &,
   init,
   100][[All, 1]]
```

Then,

```
ListLinePlot@buchnerLogisticMap[0.2, 3.6, Table[1, {5}]]
```

[image]