# Paging RAM in case of memory shortage issue

Tags: memory

Is there some way in Mathematica where I can issue execution of some command with letting Mathematica use my hard disk in case it is short of RAM. It will drastically reduce the speed but I am fine with it as long as I get appropriate results.

Comment: I believe this is the default behavior. Certainly you can look at the "page in" and "page out" statistics when running a big calculation and see that they become active when the RAM is fully active. And yes, it causes a significant decrease in performance when this happens.

Comment: Perhaps some information on your system and OS setup may be useful.

Comment: Paging is controlled by the OS, not (usually) the application. *Mathematica*'s behavior is just the same as for any other application that doesn't do anything special in this respect.

Comment: I believe its an important feature missing, there are softwares that can handle files bigger than their system RAM can handle.

Comment: I'm not sure this would make sense for a program like Mathematica.  Yes, programs like Photoshop do this separately from the OS.  But for Photoshop it makes sense: it can put the undo history in a file on disk because it does not need to access this information often.  Unlike Photoshop, Mathematica is a programming language and the system can't predict what's going to be used and what isn't any better than the OS can.  I think you're looking for a solution to not enough memory in the wrong place.

Comment: i guess an example would be something like `Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 2000000 {1, 1}] // Rasterize` which says "Not enough memory" and its like, boo hoo mathematica i dont want complaining i want results

Comment: Take a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36/file-backed-lists-variables-for-handling-large-data/209#209) instead.

Comment: Mathematica 9 supports (limited) out-of-core (which is really "not in virtual memory") image processing with `ImageFileApply`, `ImageFileFilter` and `ImageFileScan`. General-purpose, run time efficient out-of-core algorithms are untrivial; if you have resources to implement your own application-specific algorithms, you can access files as streams and seek them using `SetStreamPosition`.

Comment: This Wolfram blog post describes out-of-core image processing in Mathematica 9: [Gigapixel Images in Mathematica](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/04/29/gigapixel-images-in-mathematica/)

Comment: Note that in as long as you don't have a single internal command (like `Rasterize`) that eats up all your memory, you can always use `DumpSave` (and `Clear`) to make use of the hard disk

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom: ya but it is saving function definition and usually the code size is not a problem.

Comment: @Blackbird you can store anything you can put in a variable using `Dumpsave` (which in Mathematica I guess is anything). Not just your code. So you can also store the enormous list corresponding to the excel sheet you imported and save it using `DumpSave`, which you can retrieve faster, I think.

Comment: You can use Export to write (fast to read) MX files.  It is often more convenient than DumpSave for *data* (not code).

Comment: @Szabolcs .mx: fast to read, but sometimes dead slow to write

Comment: Good comments @Szabolcs and Yves. Maybe we should have another Q&A about this. I always assumed `Dumpsave` was kind of equivalent to `Export` to .mx

Comment: @Jacob The difference is that with DumpSave you save the definitions associated with a symbol.  When you load the file, the symbol and its definitions are simply recreated (and you have to remember what the name of the symbol was).  If you use Export, you export only some data (an expression), without associating it with a symbol. When you Import it, Import returns the data itself.

Comment: @Szabolcs then I would assume that the result of exporting a large list will be almost the same as DumpSaving it, in terms of size of the file and the speed of loading the data again, is that correct? Yves seems to disagree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To illustrate my comment, the following function allows the user to store definitions on the hard disk, clearing them from RAM, and retrieve them on-demand.

To keep things orderly, I first create a directory.

```
CreateDirectory[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "DumpSaves"}]]
```

Then this defines the function. `toHD` is short for to harddrive/hard disk.

```
SetAttributes[toHD, HoldAllComplete]

toHD[var_] :=
 With[
  {
   fnP = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "DumpSaves", 
      ToString[Unevaluated[var]] <> ".mx"}]
   },
  DumpSave[fnP, var];
  ClearAll[Unevaluated[var]];
  SetDelayed[
   var,
   ClearAll[Unevaluated[var]]; Get[fnP]; var
   ]
  ]
```

We then have

```
list = {1, 2, 3};
toHD[list];
list//Definition
```

--> list := Get[
      FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "DumpSaves", 
        ToString[Unevaluated[list]] <> ".mx"}]]

We can then do

```
Append[list, 4]
```

-> {1,2,3,4}

I am actually baffled that it works in the following case

```
toHD[list];
AppendTo[list, 4]
```

-> {1,2,3,4}

```
list//Definition
```

-> list = {1, 2, 3, 4}

**More examples**

```
f[x_] := x^2;
f[0, 1] = 2;
f//Definition
```

-> {
 {f[0, 1] = 2},
 { },
 {f[x_] := x^2}
}

Then,

```
toHD[f]
f[3]
```

-> 9

Here, doing

```
toHD[f]
f[0, 2]:=3
```

...will actually also not break it

```
f // Definition
```

> f[0, 1] = 2 
>   f[0, 2] := 3 
>   f[x_] := x^2

Wow I can't seem to beat it :)

**In case something breaks**

Maybe we could somehow put additional definitions added to a stored symbol on a queue or something. In this way we might fix additional definitions made by Set and SetDelayed. This is possible, because of the following. We can do

```
h /: SetDelayed[h, _] := Print["first"]
```

Then

```
h := 3
```

Does not define `h` to be 3, but rather prints "first". In this way we could intercept such statements and add them to some queue. Then it might be more trouble to get correct behavior for `TagSet` (if that is at all possible), but at least that is a less common function.

Comment: Todo: better formatting, testing for TagSet, Set etc, shorter out-of-office definition :P.

Comment: @Blackbird, Thank you. I think it turned out to be quite a useful function, I'm glad I made it :).

Comment: I could help you with formatting :) If you wish, I can edit your `toHD` with what my code formatter outputs for it. If you don't like it, you could roll back.

Comment: Somewhat related to your `toHD` is a function `defineCompressed` discussed in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/can-one-identify-the-design-patterns-of-mathematica/25150#25150) (under the section `Symbol's auto-loading / self-uncompression`), and in the post linked by this one, where it was originally defined.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin By all means, edit away :). But I have improved the definition of `toHD` and by sheer luck this version also looks nicer formatting wise. I must say probably your linked answer put some ideas in my head, as it looks familiar and I was also thinking about `Compress` all the time :). I wonder what the tradeoff is between `Compress` and `DumpSave` here.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Actually, I looked at how it would look and decided not to edit, partially because of the SE code rendenring bugs regarding the use of symbols with `$` in them. [Here](http://pastebin.com/KVwNrgUQ) is how it looks, just in case.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin it still looks pretty good :). But I think we can keep it like this. Did your formatter [pretty-print](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint#Lisp_pretty-printer) the result automatically? I have been thinking about making a pretty printer a long time, but if you have made it already, I prefer using that :). I think that can be useful in meta-programming, if you have defined a function indirectly and you what to see what you have defined.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom *"Did your formatter pretty-print the result automatically?"* - yes, that's exactly what it does. In case you have not seen,[here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/code-formatting-automation-for-our-posts) is a description. It is now quite easy to use for SE posts, and I already used it for a number of my recent answers. It does contain a number of bugs though, which I hope to address soon, but you can give it a try.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Ahh, yes, I did see it and even installed and tried it, but somehow I now remembered it to be a tool to preserve original formatting (or something). Now I see that it handles large expressions quite impressively. Silly of me, I should read your posts more carefully.