# Separately storing data using DumpSave in the case of Saving RAM?

Tags: time-series, datastore

Recently I am dealing with very large datasets and always ran out of RAM. A solution I found is the answer from [**Jacob Akkerboom**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28007/paging-ram-in-case-of-memory-shortage-issue). There he defined function (`toHD`) allowing users to store definitions on the hard disk, clearing them from RAM, and retrieve them on-demand.

```
pSite = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "DumpSaves"}];
If[DirectoryQ[pSite] == False, CreateDirectory[pSite]];
SetAttributes[toHD, HoldAllComplete]

toHD[var_] := 
 With[{fnP = 
    FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "DumpSaves", 
      ToString[Unevaluated[var]] <> ".mx"}]}, DumpSave[fnP, var];
  ClearAll[Unevaluated[var]];
  SetDelayed[var, ClearAll[Unevaluated[var]]; Get[fnP]; var]
  ]

(*simple example*)
Lists = ConstantArray[{}, 3];
testdate = {{1, 2, 3}};
Lists[[1]] = testdate ;
Lists[[2]] = testdate ;
Lists[[3]] = testdate ;
toHD[Lists];
```

*It works perfectly fine* and data will be stored in the **Lists.mx** file in the DampSaves folder. But **it doesn't work for** `toHD[Lists[[1]]];` if one want to store certain elements in Lists. I try to modified the `toHD[var_]` to `toHDtest[var_, num_]`:

```
toHDtest[var_, indx_] := 
 With[{fnP = 
    FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "DumpSaves", 
      ToString[Unevaluated[var[[indx]]]] <> ".mx"}]}, DumpSave[fnP, var[[indx]]];
  ClearAll[Unevaluated[var[[indx]]]];
  SetDelayed[var[[indx]], ClearAll[Unevaluated[var[[indx]]]]; Get[fnP]; var[[indx]]]
  ]
toHDtest[Lists,1]; (*expect to store Lists[[1]]*)
```

**Well it failed again because it is not a Symbol,** then I do the following:

> Let's say that I have a list of symbols such as `Lists1`,`Lists2`,... and each was given by certain processed large data. I would like to **store them in the memory separately**, such that it also doesn't need a very long computational time. As a simple example (`testdata`and `Num` is actually very large , here just for example):

```
(*just for test and give to List1,List2,...Listn . actually there are many datalist.*)
testdate = {{1, 2, 3}}; 
Num = 2;
For[ii = 1, ii <= Num, ii++,
  ToExpression["Lists" <> ToString[ii], InputForm, Function[name, name = testdate, HoldAll]];
  toHD[ToExpression["Lists" <> ToString[ii]]];
 ]
```

**Question:** I want to store the every element in `Lists` to **separated .mx files** such as Lists1.mx, Lists2.mx and so on. But **it also doesn't work** and give error as the case `toHD[lists[[1]]];` or `toHDtest[Lists,1];` .

Anyone knows how to deal with such situation or any hints? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It doesn’t work because DumpSave specifically saves the *definitions* associated with a symbol. `Lists` is a symbol; its parts, however, are not...

Comment: @MarcoB, thank you for answering. oh, .. too bad it is not possible because I don't want to create many symbols. :(

Comment: @MarcoB, what do you think dynamically changing the symbols before using DumpSave? something like `"Lists" <> ToString[ii]` ?

Comment: Aside from the `toHD[…]`, probably the last example is still wrong, the `name=testdate` should probably be `name=testdate[[1, ii]]`. And why not `Clear[Lists1, Lists2, Lists3]; MapIndexed[(Evaluate@
     Symbol["Lists" <> ToString@#2[[1]]] = #) &, testdate[[1]]]`?

Comment: @xzczd, thank you for the answer. Well, the last example is not wrong. There I didn't require `Lists1` must be `1`, it was `List1=testdate` just for example to give data (for simplicity, there i just make them all are `testdate`, they can be different ). Sorry for making the confusion,I briefly edit.