# Text analysis and loops

Tags: import

I need a loop for a text analysis involving about 1000 papers (identical structure of all papers)

I have these two commands to read all the papers into memory.

```
papers = 
  Table[
    StringJoin[{"/Users/maxmüller/Desktop/Arbeit/Info Jan2014/", ToString[i], ".pdf"}], 
    {i, 1, 1000}]

AllPaper = Table[Import[paper], {paper, papers}];
```

This is a too big a dataset for my laptop to hold in main memory, so I want to select the relevant info before I load all the data in the loop. I need following info for my analysis:

```
DOI = FindList["/Users/maxmüller/Desktop/Arbeit/Info/1.pdf", "ARTICLEDOI"]

Author = FindList["/Users/maxmüller/Desktop/Arbeit/Info/1.pdf", "/Author"]

Volume = FindList["/Users/maxmüller/Desktop/Arbeit/Info/1.pdf", "Vol.", 1]
```

It would be great if someone could help me to creat an efficient command for my analysis.

Answer (score 4):

The framework I developed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36/file-backed-lists-variables-for-handling-large-data/209#209) should be well-suited for this task. All you have to do is to write a converter from your papers into the list structure. But, it is very easy to do.

To load the framework, you could either grab all code pieces together from that post and evaluate, or (much simpler), call:

```
Import["https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lshifr/2696189/raw/largeData.m"]
```

Next, note that by default, a cross-platform but much slower option which uses `Compress` is used to store the list chunks. You may want to execute this, after you  load the main code, but before you start your work:

```
$fileNameFunction = mxFileName;
$importFunction  = mxImport ;
$exportFunction = mxExport ;
$compressFunction = Identity;
$uncompressFunction = Identity;
```

to switch to using `.mx` files, which are much faster (assuming that you won't frequently change machines / platforms). See the examples in the linked post for more details.

Assuming that you have that code loaded, you basically need something like (the `papers` variable is the same as you defined in the question):

```
initList[allpapers];
Do[appendTo[allpapers,Import[paper]],{paper, papers}]; 
storeMainList[allpapers, DestinationDirectory :> "your-directory-to-store-chunks"]
```

and then you can work with the `allpapers` variable as with a usual list, in many respects, just that it won't all be in-memory at once. See the mentioned link for examples of use, and the linked questions too.

To load the list in a different session, you have to load the framework's code and use

```
retrieveMainList[allpapers, DestinationDirectory :> "your-directory-to-store-chunks"]
```

If you later change the list (add more elements or delete some), you will have to call `storeMainList` again, for these changes to persist on disk.

Comment: thank you for the answert. Now I tried to select my infos like: Volume = FindList[allpapers, "Vol.", 1] but it doesn't work with the variable allpapers

Comment: @user3578756 You have to go though examples in the post I linked, and understand the structure of the `allpapers` variable. It is *not* a usual list, however , a number of usual list operations work on it. You will have to use something like `FindList[allpapers[[12]], "Vol.", 1] `, if, for example, you are interested in a paper #12. Note also that, once you take the part, it resides in memory, so, if you no longer need it at the moment, it is a good idea to call `releasePart[allpapers, 12]`, if you don't need it any more. It will be again loaded when you call `allpapers[[12]]` next time.

Comment: @user3578756 To go through the list, you can use for example this sort of code: `map[f_,lst_]:=Table[With[{result = f[lst[[i]]]},releasePart[lst,i]; result],{i,Length[lst]}]`, and then use `map[FindList[#,"Vol.", 1]&, allpapers]`. And so on - it is quite easy to build your own iteration and other functions. You just have to understand how these structures work, and decide when you want to release the loaded parts from memory.

Comment: @user3578756 Basically, the way these pseudo-lists work is very simple: 1. when you call `wallpapers[[i]]`, the `i`-th part of the "list" is loaded from disk to memory and is returned every time you call `allpapers[[i]]` - residing in memory after you first call this. 2. When you call `releasePart[allpapers, i]`, it gets *unloaded* from memory, so that the next time you call `allpapers[[i]]`, it will be loaded to memory again. And that's it - everything else you do with these parts, including iteration through them, or how many you want to keep in memory at once, etc, is completely up to you.

Comment: @user3578756 There are a few functions like `Take`, `Drop`, `First`, `Last`, `Rest`, `Most`, which I included and which work "out of the box", but generally you can always add your own.