# How to control memory consumption of FoldList

Tags: functions, memory

I have dealing a lot recently with the built-in function `FoldList`. I use it to solve a stochastic differential equation (SDE) in forward manner. My equation contains long-time memory, which is why `FoldList` needs to invoke a long list of values as input in order to compute the subsequent value (or rather list). Depending on the number of total steps I use in my program this can be very memory consuming which turns out to be a problem as I need to solve the equation for long times, unfortunately.

In principle, what I need from `FoldList` is only the final list of values after the last time step. The previous lists are only used as an input to compute the next value which is then appended to the previous list (while dropping the first value of this list such that the length remains constant).

Of course, `FoldList` gives me as an output not only the final list, but all the lists which where previously used as an input.

My question therefore is: Is there any way to dismiss these previous lists in order to save memory? I don't know whether this is feasible since I need the previous lists as input in `FoldList` to compute the next value. Any other ideas suggestions how to save memory are highly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

**[Edit]**

Sorry I was a little bit misled. I do not need the last list of `FoldList`, but always the last value of all the lists (including the last list and previous ones). `Fold` works fine and gives me the last list, but the length of my list is restricted by the time of memory I consider. So I could use `Fold` but then the length of this list needs to be as long as the number of lists I used in `FoldList`. Probably this slows it down very much.

**[Edit2]**

Minimum working example:

```
nMem=5;
nTot=10;  

FoldList[{#2,Drop[Append[{#1[[2]]}, Last[#1[[2]]] + 5] // Flatten,1]} &, {0, {ConstantArray[0, nMem]} // Flatten}, Range[1, nTot]]
```

which gives as an output:

```
{{0, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {1, {0, 0, 0, 0, 5}}, {2, {0, 0, 0, 5, 
   10}}, {3, {0, 0, 5, 10, 15}}, {4, {0, 5, 10, 15, 20}}, {5, {5, 10, 
   15, 20, 25}}, {6, {10, 15, 20, 25, 30}}, {7, {15, 20, 25, 30, 
   35}}, {8, {20, 25, 30, 35, 40}}, {9, {25, 30, 35, 40, 
   45}}, {10, {30, 35, 40, 45, 50}}}
```

number of time step is stored as 1,2,3,4,... (in principle not necessary).
New value is computed and appended to the list while dropping the first value of the previous list.

The `Range[1, nTot]` is desirable because when computing the new value I need to call a list with `listNoise[[#2]]`.

Length of the sublist (here 5 elements) defines nMem. Number of sublists (here 10) defines nTot.

This eats up all my memory when I increase nMem and nTot to large values.
In the end I collect only the last values from each sublist  (i.e., here `{5,10,15,20,...}`).

How can this be done more efficiently memory-wise? Maybe you even have some advice on how to improve the performance.

I tried the suggestion with `Fold` but it seems to be too bad on the performance side since in this case I need to set nMem=nTot.

**[Edit3]**

New try of a minimum working example to illustrate my intention:

```
nMem = 5;
nTot = 10;

listnoise = RandomInteger[5, nTot];
listmem = Range[nMem];

FoldList[{#2, 
   Drop[Append[{#1[[2]]}, 
      Last[#1[[2]]] + listmem.#1[[2]] + listnoise[[#2]]] // Flatten, 
    1]} &, {0, {ConstantArray[0, nMem]} // Flatten}, Range[1, nTot]]
```

Comment: Have you seen `Fold`?

Comment: No, I wasn't aware of `Fold`. Does this really save me the day in terms of memory? Because I am afraid that internally also `Fold` needs to store these intermediate lists somewhere, which would make my problem of memory consumption unsolvable. I am just wondering whether my huge memory consumption is because of the length of the final list or because of the internal mechanism of `FoldList` itself. It appears that already while `FoldList` is being evaluated the memory consumption heavily increases. So I don't know whether `Fold` makes any difference. But it is worth a try for sure!

Comment: And I also wonder whether in my case I can simply replace `FoldList` with `Fold` since I definitely need the previous list to compute the next list after one time step. Are these previous lists still available (or rather accessible) in `Fold` as it is the case in `FoldList`? Because if not it would kill the idea of my program unfortunately. In `FoldList` I simply call them via `#1[[2]].`

Comment: Sorry I was a little bit misled. I do not need the last list of `FoldList`, but always the last value of all the lists (including the last list and previous ones). `Fold` works fine and gives me the last list, but the length of my list is restricted by the time of memory I consider. So I could use `Fold` but then the length of this list needs to be as long as the number of lists I used in `FoldList`. Probably this slows it down very much.

Comment: Yeah, then it is way to slow when I use `Fold`. Each computation steps needs then much more time (since the memory list I fold in has to be much larger). This is a pity, as it seems to be a trade-off between memory saving (`Fold`) and speed (`FoldList`) in my case. What I can try to this is to restrict the list I fold in with `Fold` only to number of memory I need. I wonder whether this speeds it up again.

Comment: Tried to restrict the list I use in `Fold` with `#1[[2]][[...]]` part specification such that only the necessary numbers (the duration of the system to remember) of values are fold in. But it is still pretty much slower compared to `FoldList`. This is a pity because memory-wise it's almost consuming nothing.

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to rewrite the function so that you can use `Nest` instead?

Comment: I think `Nest` does not work with two slots, doesn't it? I need that second slot to fold in the noise, though.

Answer (score 1):

### First attempt

I think we may need a concrete example to understand your needs and the performance you are experiencing.  I think you are describing something like this:

```
FoldList[# + RotateRight[#, #2] &, Range@5, {3, 1, 5, 2}]

Last /@ %
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {4, 6, 8, 5, 7}, {11, 10, 14, 13, 12},
>  {22, 20, 28, 26, 24}, {48, 44, 50, 46, 52}}
>
> {5, 7, 12, 24, 52}
> ```

Where `{5, 7, 12, 24, 52}` is the output that you require.  If this is fairly representative of what you are doing then perhaps use:

```
x = Range[5];

FoldList[Last[x = x + RotateRight[x, #2]] &, Last @ x, {3, 1, 5, 2}]
```

> ```
> {5, 7, 12, 24, 52}
> ```

Or:

```
x = Range[5];

Prepend[
 Last[x = x + RotateRight[x, #]] & /@ {3, 1, 5, 2},
 Last @ x
]
```

> ```
> {5, 7, 12, 24, 52}
> ```

---

### Reply to Edit2

I find the example given in **Edit2** confusing.  First you don't actually need the element over which you fold as you write: "number of time step is stored as 1,2,3,4,... (in principle not necessary)."  Second you are appending to a list that is not actually used in the following step of computation.  I don't know if it is implied that in actuality it is used or not.  The operation itself amounts to nothing more than:

```
NestList[# + 5 &, 0, 10]
```

> ```
> {0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50}
> ```

If you need the previous *n* results at each step of your actual computation then manually assigning these to a Symbol like `x` as I did above should be practical.

Another approach is to replace `FoldList` with `Fold` and [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) only those results that you need at the end.  So something like:

```
Reap[
  Fold[
    Append[Rest@#, Sow[Last@# + 5]] &,
    ConstantArray[0, 5],
    Range@10
  ]
][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50}
> ```

This might be easier to apply in your actual computation, whatever it is.

### Examples for Edit3

The `Sow` and `Reap` method mentioned last above applied to your example in **Edit3**:

```
Reap[
  Fold[
    Append[Rest@#, Sow[Last[#] + listmem.# + #2]] &,
    ConstantArray[0, nMem],
    listnoise
  ]
][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {5, 31, 206, 1379, 9201, 61411, 409851, 2735319, 18255333, 121834850}
> ```

The manual assignment to `x`:

```
x = ConstantArray[0, nMem];

FoldList[
  Last[x = Append[Rest@x, # + listmem.x + #2]] &,
  0,
  listnoise
]
```

> ```
> {0, 5, 31, 206, 1379, 9201, 61411, 409851, 2735319, 18255333, 121834850}
> ```

Comment: Yes, in principle that's what the program needs to do. However, I need to invoke a noise term. So far I solved it by pre-computing the noise in a list and then fold in that list via the second slot of `FoldList`, i.e. something like `listNoise[[#2]]` appears within `FoldList`. This means I need the second slot in `FoldList` to go from 1 to nTot via `Range[1,nTot]`, where nTot is the number of time steps. Now, in your solution both slots are already occupied. This seems to be a problem.

Comment: @DisplayName I'm sorry but I don't seem be to able to follow your description.  I gave an example with `FoldList` where both slots are used normally, and then two methods that give the same result without accumulating lists at every step.  I don't see why these methods cannot be applied to your case as well.  I hope you will add a minimum working example to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been given a minimum working example from the very beginning. See my edit in the OP please. And I was wrong, my intention is slightly different compared to your suggestion.

Comment: Please see my latest Edit3. This should be now more accurate to illustrate my intention. Hope I could resolve your confusion and the two points you mentioned at the beginning of your reply to Edit2.

Comment: @DisplayName I applied the proposed methods to your example in Edit3.

Comment: This is great and solves almost all my problems. It's not only almost twice as fast as my initial solution (the manual assignment to `x` seems to be equally fast on my machine as the method with `Reap` and `Sow`) but is almost not at all memory consuming. Just one further question out of curiosity: I need to define the list `listnoise` at some point. This is supposed to be a huge list. Is there any way to compress the size of a huge list in Mathematica? In any case I should be save on a machine with lot of memory. I need to check how much data in a list can be stored on a 6 GB PC.

Comment: And by the way thank you very much for your help and perseverance.

Comment: @DisplayName That may depend somewhat on the content of your list.  If possible make sure it is a [packed array.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/121)  If all values are 0-255 look at `ByteArray`.  If most of the elements are the same look at `SparseArray`.  If all these fail see [(36)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36/121)

Comment: I tried to use a packed array. The command `Developer`FromPackedArray[]` reduces the `ByteCount[]` of the list by 1/3. However, `Developer`ToPackedArray` doesn't seem to have any effect. `ByteArray` is not useable as the list also contains negative values and non-integers. Also the elements are different, unfortunately. I will look at your last suggestion in detail soon (this will take more time, of course to understand it properly).

Comment: I am just wondering whether there is a way to tell Mathematica that the list contains only (real floating-point) numbers, since lists in Mathematica are quite general (e.g. they can contain images etc.). I don't know whether one has to specify this by one's own or it is automatically recognized by Mathematica itself and treated in the best way available.

Comment: @DisplayName Check if your list is already a packed array using ``Developer`PackedArrayQ``.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard: `Developer\`PackedArrayQ` returns `False` for my initial list. Later I sum the elements of this list with the elements of another list and then `Developer\`PackedArrayQ` returns `True`.

Comment: Ok I could adapt my code such that now also the initial list is a packed array.

Comment: I noticed that your solution with `Reap` and `Sow` is always a packed array, while the solution with manual assignment is always unpacked. Why is this so?

Comment: Ok, one needs to use `Developer\`ToPackedArray[...,Real]` as I figured out.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard: Another problem that arose: I need now a third "variable" within the `Append[Rest@x, # + listmem.x + #2]]` that tracks the number of the current iteration, i.e. counting up from 1,2,3,... Is this (hidden) iterator within `FoldList` somehow accessible? I know `FoldList` allows only two slots. I though about pre-computing these numbers in `listnoise`. Is there any smarter way how one could do this?

Comment: @DisplayName I'm glad you worked out most of this while I was away.  For the latest point I suppose you can go back to Folding over `Range @ Length @ listnoise` and using `listnoise[[#2]]` -- or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
Clear[f, g]
(*FoldList*)
f[bs_, a_] := Append[bs, a^2]
FoldList[f, {1}, Range[2, 10]] // Map[Last]

(*instead of FoldList, use Fold*)
g[{cs_List, bs_List}, a_] := Module[{$bs},
  $bs = f[bs, a];
  {Append[cs, Last@$bs], $bs}]
Fold[g, {{}, {}}, Range[1, 10]] // First
```

Out:

```
{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}
{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}
```