# Classifier training on a large data set

Tags: performance-tuning, machine-learning

I am interested in binary classification and I have a huge set of training examples (around 4 millions). Each example is a $10 \times 2$ matrix. When I run the classification after two hour run the kernel failed. (I used Windows 10 and WL 12.)

Any suggestion on how to run it?

**Remark:** This question is about on-boarding a large data set into WL's classifier training. It is not (that much) about getting good classification results. Something similar to the approach presented in the tutorial ["Training on Large Datasets"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksLargeDatasets.html).

Model training code:

```
rfModel = 
        Classify[traningSet, 
           Method -> {"RandomForest", "LeafSize" -> 6, "TreeNumber" -> 850}, 
           TrainingProgressReporting -> "Print"];
```

An example of training data:

```
{{{0.0249777, 250., 0.012, 0.117647, 20., -0.0735972, 4., 1235., 0., 1.},   
  {0.0178571, 41., 0.0243902, 0., 5., 0.926403, 5., 456., 0., 1.}} -> 1.,
 {{-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -0.0735972, 4., 1075., 0., 1.}, 
  {0.0255319, 469., 0.0234542, 0.037037, 57., -2.0736, 2., 79., 0., 0.}} -> 1., 
 {{-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.0736, 3., 1706., 0., 0.}, 
  {-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -0.0735972, 4., 2402., 0., 1.}} -> 1.}
```

Comment: Please provide a larger sample of your data. Also, at first you probably do not need to train with all 4 million records. See do you get any good results with a smaller (representative) sample.

Comment: @AntonAntonov it is a link to the data https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdolcupy6e9swzh/traningSet.mx?dl=0. Long story short, this classification task is part of my research.  I try to compare between few approaches to create a synthetic training data ( I don't get a good result with small data set this is a resson to try to incease the dataset).

Comment: Thanks for providing the data! I downloaded it, I will investigate later today.

Comment: Is it a memory limitation? You could use Leonid Shifrin's very clever filesystem-backed list: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36/file-backed-lists-variables-for-handling-large-data/209#209. Or use ActiveClassification to which you can supply your own data reader function. You could also cook your own classifier with NetTrain/NetEncoder as in the tutorial. Mathematica tends to choke on large in-memory datasets, so aim for out-of-core.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*After posting this answer OP clarified the question with:*

> To be more specific, I am not looking for the solution which will improve my result but, for the one which will allow me to load a big trining set.

*This answer is about getting good classification results over a large dataset, not about on-boarding large datasets into `Classify`.*

### Investigation steps

A list of the steps I took follows.

1. Download the data and import it.
2. Basic data analysis.

   - There are duplicates in the data.
   - Removed them with `Union`.
3. Flatten the 2D arrays.
4. Further data analysis.
    For example, applying SVD produced 3-5 significant vectors.
    That though was not that useful for the classification.
5. Take a sample of 10^5 or 3*10^5 records and do classification experiments.
    Relatively good results were obtained.
6. Use large samples, e.g. 1.5*10^6 records.
7. Turned out that using a training set sample of ~5*10^4 and doing classification over the rest produced fairly good results.

For the experiments I used the package ["MonaticContextualClassification.m"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/MonadicProgramming/MonadicContextualClassification.m). See the article ["A monad for classification workflows"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2018/05/15/a-monad-for-classification-workflows/).

The important class label is the label "0" (or "No" below) because only ~13% of the records have it. Using the ROC curves and selecting the threshold 0.175 with the obtained classifier produced the following classifier performance measures:

```
(* <|FalsePositiveRate-><|No->0.138243,Yes->0.124086|>,
     Recall-><|No->0.875914,Yes->0.861757|>,
     Specificity-><|No->0.861757,Yes->0.875914|>,
     MatthewsCorrelationCoefficient-><|No->0.737745,Yes->0.737745|>,
     Accuracy->0.863442|> *)
```

I assume the overall accuracy and class label recall shown above are satisfactory. If not further experiments can be done using classifier ensembles, removing outliers, etc.

### Code

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 trainingSet = Import["~/Downloads/traningSet.mx"];
]
Length[trainingSet]

(* {3.36351, Null}

   3467240 *)

(* Remove duplicates. *)
AbsoluteTiming[
 trainingSet2 = Union[trainingSet];
]
Length[trainingSet2]

(* {16.4582, Null}
    3312223 *)

(* Flatten 2D arrays. *) 
trainingSet2[[All, 1]] = Flatten /@ trainingSet2[[All, 1]];
Dimensions[trainingSet2[[All, 1]]]

(* {3312223, 20} *)

(* See the class labels representation. *)
Tally[trainingSet2[[All, 2]]]

(* {{1., 2918036}, {0., 394187}} *)

(* Using categorical labels. *)
trainingSet2[[All, 2]] = trainingSet2[[All, 2]] /. {1. -> "Yes", 0. -> "No"};
Tally[trainingSet2[[All, 2]]]

(* {{"Yes", 2918036}, {"No", 394187}} *)

(* Taking relatively smaller sample. *)
SeedRandom[3439]
trainingSet2Small = RandomSample[trainingSet2, 3*10^5];

(* Load the ClCon package. *)
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/\
MathematicaForPrediction/master/MonadicProgramming/\
MonadicContextualClassification.m"]

(* Importing from GitHub: StateMonadCodeGenerator.m

   Importing from GitHub: ClassifierEnsembles.m

   Importing from GitHub: ROCFunctions.m

   Importing from GitHub: VariableImportanceByClassifiers.m *)

(* Application of the software monad ClCon. *)
AbsoluteTiming[
 clObj =
   ClConUnit[trainingSet2Small]⟹
    ClConSplitData[0.2, 0.2]⟹
    ClConTrainClassifier[{"GradientBoostedTrees"}]⟹
    ClConClassifierMeasurements⟹
    ClConEchoValue⟹
    ClConROCPlot["FPR", "TPR", ImageSize -> 350]⟹
    ClConROCListLinePlot[{"TPR", "FPR", "SPC", "MCC", "Accuracy"}, ImageSize -> 350];
 ]
```

[image]

```
 (* {70.5563, Null} *)


(* This gets the classifier: *)
(clObj⟹ClConTakeClassifier)[[1]]

(* This verifies that the obtained classifier produces good results \
with the selected threshold, 0.175 . *)
AbsoluteTiming[
 ClConUnit[]⟹
   ClConSetTestData[trainingSet2]⟹
   ClConSetClassifier[clObj⟹ClConTakeClassifier]⟹
   ClConClassifierMeasurementsByThreshold[{ "FalsePositiveRate", "Recall", "Specificity", "MatthewsCorrelationCoefficient", "Accuracy"}, "No" -> 0.175]⟹
   ClConEchoValue;
 ]

(* value: <|FalsePositiveRate-><|No->0.138243,Yes->0.124086|>,
            Recall-><|No->0.875914,Yes->0.861757|>,
            Specificity-><|No->0.861757,Yes->0.875914|>,
            MatthewsCorrelationCoefficient-><|No->0.737745,Yes->0.737745|>,
            Accuracy->0.863442|> *)

(* {229.404, Null} *)
```

Comment: thank you. I do not familiar with this package, and it  looks very helpful. 
Unfortunatlly, I am looking for a solution which use all the training set, my current problem is that the WL kernel is failed when I use all data in Classify. 

To be more specific, I am not looking for the solution which will  improve my result but, for the one which will allow  me to load a big trining set. 

Something similar to approach  presented in the following tutorial :https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksLargeDatasets.html

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko Ok. Please add the last sentence of your comment to your question.

Comment: I should have read through this answer more carefully. It's better than mine. In any case, @KirilDanilchenko, Anton's answer will likely work for your full dataset. I just did the simplest thing and it worked.

Comment: @RobertJacobson Well, and if I clarified with OP what exactly he wants, I would not have spent time researching and posting my answer. I am almost embarrassed I did... (I should have payed attention to these sentences from OP's comments: "I try to compare between few approaches to create a synthetic training data. I don't get a good result with small data set this is a reason to try to increase the dataset.")

Comment: @RobertJacobson actually my question is not about the data science "tricks and tips" but the technical problem of WL to on-boarding  a huge data set.

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko Your technical problem was solved by fixing your dataset. I get no errors, even with millions of data elements, after fixing the dataset.

Comment: @RobertJacobson Do you use the whole data set (without duplicate), and also which version of WL do you use and what OS. When I train the model at 2 millions of examples, it runs well but at about the 2.6 (and more)  millions of examples  it gets error

Comment: @KirilDanilchenko I *can* use the entire (deduplicated) dataset, yes. To reiterate, doing so would be not merely non-optimal but *incorrect*. I used v.12 on MacOS Mojave. It ran to completion. I forget how long it took. It was over an hour but less than 3 hours. It used ~4 GB RAM, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 4):

## The Problem

We have a training set of ~2.7 million elements with which we wish to train a random forest classifier. However, Mathematica errors out before the classifier is finished training.

#### What Went Wrong

Mathematica can have trouble with large datasets, but that isn't the problem here. Let's investigate the data:

```
 AbsoluteTiming[trainingSet = Union[Import["~/Downloads/trainingSet.mx"]];
 {Length[trainingSet], 
     Length[trainingSet] - Length[DeleteDuplicates[trainingSet]]}
```

> ```
> {16.9372,Null}
> {2748500, 14522}
> ```

One problem is that the training set has duplicate elements. Since we are training a binary classifier, we want the categories to be equally represented. Let's check the distribution.

```
Count[Union[trainingSet], _ -> 1.0]
```

> ```
> 2160225
> ```

So of the 2733978 unique elements, ~80% of them are in category 1.  This is not a good training set, because flipping a coin will give an accuracy of 80%.

#### Training with adjusted data

We split the dataset up into a training set and a test set, each of which are equal parts category 0 and category 1 data. Note that I am using 100% of the 0 category data to do this.

```
trainingSet = DeleteDuplicates[Import["~/Downloads/trainingSet.mx"]];
SeedRandom[42];
trainingSet = 
  RandomSample[
   Join[RandomSample[Select[trainingSet, Last[#] == 1.0 &], 573753], 
    Select[trainingSet, Last[#] == 0.0 &]]];
{trainingSet, testSet} = {Take[trainingSet, 573753], 
   Take[trainingSet, -573753]};
```

Train and save the result to disk just in case. I'm using the notebook frontend, so I use `TrainingProgressReporting -> "Panel"`.

```
rfModel = 
   Classify[trainingSet, 
   Method -> {"RandomForest", "LeafSize" -> 6, "TreeNumber" -> 850}, 
   TrainingProgressReporting -> "Panel"];
DumpSave["~/Downloads/rfModel.mx", rfModel];
```

#### Evaluate the performance

It's always best to create a `ClassifierMeasurementsObject` so you don't have to run the test again.

```
cmo = ClassifierMeasurements[rfModel, testSet];
cmo["Report"]
```

> [image]

```
Transpose[{
    {"MatthewsCorrelationCoefficient", "CohenKappa", "EvaluationTime"}, 
    cmo /@ {"MatthewsCorrelationCoefficient", "CohenKappa", "EvaluationTime"}
}] // TableForm
```

> ```
> MatthewsCorrelationCoefficient  <|0.->0.917584,1.->0.917584|>
> CohenKappa                      0.916081
> EvaluationTime                  0.0371
> ```

If you set it loose on your entire 2,733,978, be sure to use something like the [Matthews Correlation Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient) to account for the fact that you have wildly different numbers of elements in each category.

Comment: In the last update of my answer I added Mathews Correlation Coefficient (MCC) plots.